# How to define a if-condition?

Tags: conditionals

I found several entries about the fact that the `ifthen` package is [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete). So my question is: how to define a condition check then? I have searched and I find several example for `ifthenelse` (contained in the `ifthen`) package OR the statement *"ifthen package is obsolete"*.

Comment: it is _not_ obsolete

Comment: @Herbert I agree; maybe it's not the first choice any more, but it's easy and in some cases it's sufficient. Probably using `xifthen` in place of it is better anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be considered obsolete because there exist more modern variants and the package was not updated for a long time.

See for example http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox which uses e-TeX features.

Apart from the macros in ifthenelse being fragile, if you can handle that, you can just use them, no problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer

```
\def\something{} %% set to true
%% or:
\let\something\undefined %% set to false

\ifdefined\something
  True
\else
  False
\fi
```

to avoid the `ifthen` package.

The advantage of not using a package is that this approach can be used in files that are just `\input` by large document (for example `TikZ` images), when it cannot be guaranteed that a certain package is loaded.

Comment: Your code only shows how to check whether a macro is defined; I believe the OP's question is more general than that.

Comment: If you can influence setting the variable to true or false, you can also instead define or undefine it (`\let\something\undefined`)