# Identify meaning of a TeX string

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to identify the meaning of some TeX symbols.

I don't work with it or anything, it just cropped up online and I was wondering if anybody could shed any light on it.

```
\ddot{x} + \delta \dot{x} + \alpha x + \beta x^3 = \gamma cos(\omega t)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: it looks like an ordinary differential equation for an externally driven and damped oscillator

Answer (score 14):

Putting your example into a small TeX document (`cos` corrected to `\cos`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
\ddot{x} + \delta \dot{x} + \alpha x + \beta x^3 = \gamma \cos(\omega t)
\]

\end{document}
```

you have

[image]

It is easy to see that `\alpha`, `\beta` and so on generate Greek letters, `\dot` and `\ddot` provide "accents" that denote the first and second derivative of the variable `x` with respect to time `t`, and `\cos` generates the standard abbreviation for the cosine function.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of streamlining the final paragraph a bit.

Comment: There's still a word typo (correted → corrected) -- Since I hardly edit answers, I leave it to http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26134/przemys%c5%82aw-scherwentke ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Don't be too shy about using your editing rights -- you've very much earned them! :-)

Comment: @Mico: I'll start immediately and edit all your `lua` based answers ;-)

Comment: @Mico Thank you! Now it is much better than it was in my poor English. (As `poor Jane's scrofula` [Look Homeward, Angel by Thomas Wolfe]).

Comment: Well, that was easy rep :p

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - You're most welcome to try your hand at all of my answers, including [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312893/5001). :-)

Comment: @Mico: Shame on you Mico, luring me to upvote ;-)]

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Oh well, I'll have to try a new ruse from now on. ;-)