# Check equality between colors

Tags: color, logic

Consider the following:

`\colorlet{mycolour1}{black}`

AND

`\colorlet{mycolour2}{black}`

How do I use a command like

`\ifthenelse{\equal{mycolour1}{mycolour2}}{TRUE}{FALSE}`

In other words, how can I check equality between two colors?

Comment: Please accept one of the answers so that your question doesn't remain in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Werner points out, `etoolbox`'s e-TeX powerful funtionalities are preferable to what `ifthen` offers. The `\ifdefequal` is particularly handy here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifcolorsequalthenelse[4]{%
    \extractcolorspec{#1}{\@spec@A}
    \extractcolorspec{#2}{\@spec@B}
    \ifdefequal{\@spec@A}{\@spec@B}%
    {%
        #3%
    }{%
        #4%
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\colorlet{mycolor1}{red}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{1 0 0.1}

\noindent
Test 1:\ifcolorsequalthenelse{mycolor1}{red}{equal}{not equal}\\
Test 2:\ifcolorsequalthenelse{mycolor1}{mycolor2}{equal}{not equal}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I worked it out.

```
\makeatletter
   \extractcolorspec{mycolor1}{\@spec@A}
   \extractcolorspec{mycolor2}{\@spec@B}
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\@spec@A}{\@spec@B}}{
      %TRUE
   }{
      %FALSE
   }
\makeatother
```

Comment: See [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764)