# Use of a macro to set counter value in another macro

Tags: macros, counters, expansion

I am trying to simply set the value of the counter `try` which I defined previously to the value of the output of the `\foo` command. However this does not work. I guess that the problem is coming from the fact that in the `\test` macro the `\foo` one is not expanded at the right time of compilation. Since I know really few concerning macros and their expansion I am not able to find the solution here.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{try}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\ifthenelse{#1=1}{1}{0}}

\newcommand\test[1]{\setcounter{try}{\foo{#1}}%
\arabic{try}}

\begin{document}

Result of foo\{3\}: \foo{3}
Result of test\{3\}: \test{3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `\setcounter` is expanded by TeX that wants to see a `<number>` there. So you need an expandable test, which `\ifthenelse` isn't: rather than expanding to a number, it expands to the instructions for producing a number.

The easiest way is to use the primitive conditional `\ifnum`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{try}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\ifnum#1=1 1\else0\fi}

\newcommand\test[1]{\setcounter{try}{\foo{#1}}%
\arabic{try}}

\begin{document}

Result of \verb|\foo{3}|: \foo{3}
Result of \verb|test{3}|: \test{3}

Result of \verb|\foo{1}|: \foo{1}
Result of \verb|test{1}|: \test{1}

\end{document}
```

Note the space after `=1` that is necessary in all cases a “naked” constant appears (the space gets ignored by TeX).

Alternatively, use `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{try}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{1}{1}{0}}

\newcommand\test[1]{\setcounter{try}{\foo{#1}}%
\arabic{try}}

\begin{document}

Result of \verb|\foo{3}|: \foo{3}
Result of \verb|test{3}|: \test{3}

Result of \verb|\foo{1}|: \foo{1}
Result of \verb|test{1}|: \test{1}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output for both cases

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is working fine. This question led me to another one: What should I do if `\foo` is defined as `\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\StrBefore{#1}{.}}` using the `xstring` package?

Comment: @LudovicC. This has the same problem: `\StrBefore` doesn't expandably produce its result. Maybe you want to make another question better specifying your context and the expected values to argument `#1`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where the problem comes from exactly, but you'd be better off using `etoolbox` rather than `ifthen`; see [Why is the ifthen package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{try}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\ifnumequal{#1}{1}{1}{0}}

\newcommand\test[1]{\setcounter{try}{\foo{#1}}%
\arabic{try}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Result of foo\{3\}: \foo{3}\\
Result of test\{3\}: \test{3}\\
Result of foo\{1\}: \foo{1}\\
Result of test\{1\}: \test{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]