# Numbering in Beamer handout

Tags: beamer, conditionals, page-numbering

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\newcounter{slidenumber}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme frame plus slide}{
    \setcounter{slidenumber}{\insertpagenumber}%
    \addtocounter{slidenumber}{-\insertframestartpage}%
    \addtocounter{slidenumber}{1}%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
            \insertframenumber(\alph{slidenumber}{})/ \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[infolines theme frame plus slide]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \only<handout:1>{Handout 1 of frame 1}
  \only<handout:2>{Handout 2 of frame 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Frame 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Frame 1 has two slides, I want to number them as `1(a)/2`, `1(b)/2`. Frame 2 has only one slide, and is currently numbered as `2(a)/2`. However, I want to number it as `2/2`.

In general, I want frames with multiple slides numbered as

```
<frame_num>(<slide_num_in_frame>)/<total_frame_num>
```

and frames with only one slide numbered as

```
<frame_num>/<total_frame_num>
```

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ifthen package it is possible. The syntax of its if-clauses is  \ifthenelse{⟨test⟩}{⟨then clause⟩}{⟨else clause⟩}.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{slidenumber}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme frame plus slide}{
    \setcounter{slidenumber}{\insertpagenumber}%
    \addtocounter{slidenumber}{-\insertframestartpage}%
    \addtocounter{slidenumber}{1}%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
          \ifthenelse{\insertframeendpage=\insertframestartpage}{
            \insertframenumber/ \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}}{
            \insertframenumber(\alph{slidenumber}{})/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}}
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[infolines theme frame plus slide]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \only<handout:1>{Handout 1 of frame 1}
  \only<handout:2>{Handout 2 of frame 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Frame 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. I've seen that [the `ifthen` package has been obsolete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/18228). So I was researching on alternative ways of implementing the conditional. Turns out that one can simply use LaTeX's `\ifnum` command: `\ifnum\insertframeendpage=\insertframestartpage <true action> \else <false action> \fi`. I nevertheless owe you a big thank you for helping me formulate the <test> part of the conditional!

Comment: Hey, that is good. I tried with \ifnum, but was not successful in this short try. Knowing it is obsolete, I try it again and then I add it to the answer. @all: If this has not happened in the future, feel free to contact via a comment 'at'me.

Comment: Apparently for `\ifnum` to work, something like `{` needs to go between `<test>` and `<true action>`. The following works for me: `\ifnum\insertframeendpage=\insertframestartpage {\insertframenumber <...>} \else <false action> \fi`.

Comment: It also works if a letter goes between <test> and <true action>. For example, `\ifnum\insertframeendpage=\insertframestartpage page \insertframenumber <...> \else <false action> \fi`. So my guess is that if the character after <test> is a `\ `, TeX will mistakenly think that what follows is still a part of the <test>, and so something other than `\ `, e.g. `{` or a normal letter, has to be inserted at the end of <test> so that <true action> can be processed correctly.