# newcommand based on what environment is active

Tags: environments, conditionals

I want to have command to insert different heading style based on what environment is currently active. I found that the environment should be accessible via macro `\@currenvir`, but for me, the "else" branch is executed, so nothing happened.

```
\newcommand{\head}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@currenvir}{itemize}}{
        \textbf{#1}
    }{

    }   
}
```

Comment: we need a complete but minimal example

Comment: If used in your preamble, you should insert your command definition between a pair of `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform a string comparison with the expansion of `\@currenvir` against `itemize`. `\ifthenelse` with the `\equal` operator does this, but you're short a magic `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` wrapper (see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)).

Consider the post [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764), I've used the e-TeX `\pdfstrcmp` to perform a *string* comparison that is expandable below. If the (numeral) result is 0, we have a match, otherwise it's non-zero:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{itemize}=0
    \textbf{#1}% Inside itemize
  \else
    \textit{#1}% Not inside itemize
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \head{First} item
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \head{Second} item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The above usage should work for nested `itemize` as well.

---

You can also use the following `\ifx` conditional:

```
\makeatletter
\def\specialenvironment{itemize}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\specialenvironment
    \textbf{#1}% Inside "special environment"
  \else
    \textit{#1}% Not inside "special environment"
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Note also the frequent use of `%`. For the motivation, see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)