# pst-barcode Argument of \pst@@object has an extra }

Tags: errors, conditionals, pst-barcode

I have the ISBN stored in two commands (depending of a class option)

```
\theisbne
\theisbnp
```

The boolean options of the class are defined using `xifthen`

```
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\newboolean{@sbmcpm@print}
\setboolean{@sbmcpm@print}{true}
\DeclareOption{ebook}{\setboolean{@sbmcpm@print}{false}}
\DeclareOption{print}{\setboolean{@sbmcpm@print}{true}}
```

I get the selected ISBN by the command

```
\newcommand{\getisbn}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@sbmcpm@print}}{\theisbnp}{\theisbne}%
}
```

If I use `\psbarcode` directly with `\theisbne` it compiles without error.

```
 \psbarcode{\theisbne}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}
```

But if I use `\getisbn`

```
\psbarcode{\getisbn}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}
```

I got the following error:

```
! Argument of \pst@@object has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.33 ...etisbn}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}
```

Any idea where to look?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\newboolean{@sbmcpm@print}
\setboolean{@sbmcpm@print}{true}

\newcommand{\theisbne}{978-85-8337-040-6}%
\newcommand{\theisbnp}{978-85-85818-86-9}%


%%% Commands depending the options
\newcommand{\getisbn}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@sbmcpm@print}}{\theisbnp}{\theisbne}%
}

\begin{document}

\psbarcode{\getisbn}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}
%\psbarcode{\theisbne}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `@` *without* `\makeatletter` is problematic (in general). Also, the conditional for selecting between the possible bar ISBNs is [not expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13882/5764). Instead, I've used traditional `\if`-statements to condition below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@sbmcpm@print
\@sbmcpm@printtrue

%%% Commands depending the options
\newcommand{\getisbn}{%
  \if@sbmcpm@print\theisbnp\else\theisbne\fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\theisbne}{978-85-8337-040-6}%
\newcommand{\theisbnp}{978-85-85818-86-9}%

\begin{document}

\psbarcode{\getisbn}{includetext guardwhitespace}{isbn}

\end{document}
```

Here is an expandable [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) equivalent:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newbool{@sbmcpm@print}
\setbool{@sbmcpm@print}{true}

%%% Commands depending the options
\newcommand{\getisbn}{%
  \ifbool{@sbmcpm@print}{\theisbnp}{\theisbne}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the second. The original definition was in a cls file and I copu&paste to the MWE.