# Problem with \ifthenelse inside some loops

Tags: conditionals, loops

Why this code produce some value not in the diagonal? Nine in total all below the diagonal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[](.75,.75)rectangle(7.75,7.75);
\foreach \x in {1,...,7}
{
\foreach \y in {1,...,7}
{
%\pgfmathsetmacro{\rapporto}{\x/\y}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rapporto}{\x/\y}
\ifthenelse
{1=\rapporto}
{\node[scale=1,red]at(\x,\y){$\x/\y$};}
{}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please can you add or edit a compilable minimal working example?

Comment: Now it should be ok!

Comment: @yngabl no your example produces the error `! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
               there is probably something wrong with the class file.`

Answer (score 3):

It is because the `\pgftruncatemacro` will truncate your result, then some combinations of `\x` and `\y` will give `1`. Use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[](.75,.75)rectangle(7.75,7.75);
\foreach \x in {1,...,7}
{
\foreach \y in {1,...,7}
{
\ifnum\x=\y
 \node[scale=1,red]at(\x,\y){$\x/\y$};
\else
 \relax
\fi
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To see why this is the case, output the entire (7 x 7) matrix of values `\rapporto` evaluates to:

[image]

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,7} {%
  \foreach \y in {1,...,7} {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rapporto}{\x / \y}%
    \rapporto~%
  }%
  \par
}
```

You'll see that the diagonal evaluates to 1, but also other elements (since truncation of values slightly larger than 1 will result in 1). If you want to focus on the diagonal, rather consider the condition `\x = \y`. Moreover, [there is no need for `ifthen`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (.75, .75) rectangle (7.75, 7.75);
  \foreach \x in {1,...,7} {%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,7} {%
      \ifx\x\y% \x == \y
        \node [red] at (\x, \y){$\x / \y$};
      \else% \x != y
        \node [black] at (\x, \y){$\x / \y$};
      \fi
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the point of doing two loops and then just keeping the diagonal elements?

Comment: @marmot: True. I think the FALSE clause of the condition will speak to that, but it's been left empty.

Comment: I agree. I agree.