# Conditional If-then-else/xIf-then-else Packages

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse, xifthen

I'm currently working on a presentation about the packages mentioned in the title. The problem I have is, I don't really understand why anyone would use conditional statements in a LaTeX document. What is the advantage of using such statements? Could you give me a real world application, something where they are actually helpful for the "mainstream" LaTeX-User ?

Comment: A quick example includes when someone writes an exam that includes the answers with every question. Each answer is written using a specific environment, which allows one to conditionally turn them on or off, depending on whether you want to create the exam with/without answers. In essence, a single document source that could create different outputs via some condition that the user can set. Related package: [`comment`](//ctan.org/pkg/comment)

Comment: Ahh so I could use that for making one document and then compiling it into two or more different versions of itself by just changing one value? And say something like (pseudo code): if nbr == 1 then ... if nmbr == 2 ... and so on and so forth. Am I heading in the right direction ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You use conditionals to determine what properties the output needs to have/not.

Comment: Direct usage in the `document` environment should be rare, but conditionals are a very important tool in macro definitions.

Comment: What are macros ? I'm sorry but as you can see I'm very new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you use the `\ifthenelse` syntax there are all kinds of tests that one might do.

You could for instance:

- test if the height of an image is larger or smaller than its width and then decide to rotate the image or set it on a landscape page, or wherever else is appropriate
- set a boolean flag in the preamble and then conditionally include parts of a document, eg a presentation with or without notes or a question sheet with or without answers.
- make trial typesettings of some text in a box and then test the resulting size (or line breaking badness or whatever) and repeat the tests with different settings, eg smaller font sizes,  before finally using one box.
- You can make tests and vary the presentation of counters so for example make a cross reference say **section 3.2** if you are not in chapter 3 but just **section 2** if you are
- You can test the \day and use `st` or `nd` or `rd` as appropriate to make 17th June etc.

many of these tests are available as specific package commands eg `varwidth` for trial settings, or `varioref` for variant references and several packages for date formatting, but it's always possible to think of something to test which doesn't have a specific command defined in a package.

Answer (score 3):

Conditionals are used throughout the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) to aid in the typesetting of sectional units and more. The availability to the end user often allows one to create documents that can be altered with a change in a variable. That is, rather than creating two separate documents, each having basically the same content with only minor changes here and there, you can create a single document that conditions on its contents based on a variable.

As a practical example, consider someone writing up an exam for their students. They write the entire examination as a set of questions and answers, each answer being written inside an `answer` environment (say) immediately after the corresponding question. Now you can use the [`comment` package](//ctan.org/pkg/comment) to print the document without the answers (using `\excludecomment{answer}`) which prepares the actual exam, and with answers (using `\includecomment{answer}`) when you want a complete solution.

Another example comes from the cross-referencing package [`varioref`](//ctan.org/pkg/varioref) that allows the user to specify `\vref{<ref>}` in such a way that the reference changes depending on its location relative to the referenced object; "see the section **above**" or "**below**" rather than some absolute reference "see section **1.2**".

Another example from the LaTeX kernel: Printing integers to always have two digits using `\two@digits`. Here's the definition from the kernel:

```
\def\two@digits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\number#1}
```

Read as pseudocode, `\two@digits{<num>}` first checks (conditions) whether `<num>` is less than 10. If so, it prints `0`, then it prints `<num>`. This ensures that numbers less than 10 will be preceded by `0`. This conditioning allows for consistent typesetting when width of numbers are required, say. Of course, it could be used in other environments as well.

The [`ifthen`](//ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) and [`xifthen`](//ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) packages are considered [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764) since there are [other options available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764), but the principle remains the same.