# What is wrong with the use of `isodd` of `xifthen`?

Tags: nodes, foreach, xifthen, arithmetic

The white/black board can be drawn by testing the parity of node positions as follows:

[image: white-black-board]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 10pt}]
  \foreach \r in {1, ..., 4} {
    \foreach \c in {1, ..., 5} {
      \pgfmathparse{mod(\r + \c, 2)} 
      \let\parity\pgfmathresult 

      \ifthenelse{\equal{\parity}{0.0}}
      {\node (\r\c) [fill = lightgray] at (\c, \r){}}
      {\node (\r\c) at (\c, \r){}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, using `isodd` of `xifthen` does not produce the same result. What is wrong here? Or are there any alternative similar solutions?

[image: white-black-board-wrong]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 10pt}]
  \foreach \r in {1, ..., 4} {
    \foreach \c in {1, ..., 5} {
      \ifthenelse{\NOT \isodd{\r + \c}}
      {\node (\r\c) [fill = lightgray] at (\c, \r){}}
      {\node (\r\c) at (\c, \r){}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I suggest using TeX's `\ifodd` instead of `\ifthenelse` from [`xifthen`](//ctan.org/pkg/xifthen)? See [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764)

Comment: @Werner Thanks. It is also appreciated. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are implicitly assuming that isodd does calculations. But this is not what happens, it actually simply takes the begin of the argument until it hits something that is no longer a number. So you would need to do the addition first and then fed the result to isodd. Or use the tools of pgf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\isodd{124blub}}{odd}{even}

\ifthenelse{\isodd{123blub}}{odd}{even}

\ifthenelse{\isodd{2+3}}{odd}{even}

\ifthenelse{\isodd{3+2}}{odd}{even}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 10pt}]
  \foreach \r in {1, ..., 4} {
    \foreach \c in {1, ..., 5} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\mycolor{isodd{\numexpr\r+\c}?"lightgray":"white"}
      \node (\r\c) [fill =\mycolor  ] at (\c, \r){};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest using TeX's `\ifodd` (or [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)); [`xifthen`](//ctan.org/pkg/xifthen)-and-friends may be considered [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 10pt}]
  \foreach \r in {1, ..., 4} {
    \foreach \c in {1, ..., 5} {
      \ifodd\inteval{\r+\c}
        \node (\r\c) [fill = lightgray] at (\c, \r) {};
      \else
        \node (\r\c) at (\c, \r) {};
      \fi
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I use [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) since it is convenient and provides an expandable `\inteval` for `int`eger `eval`uation that can be used in conditioning options like `\ifodd`. You can also do it without `xfp`:

```
      \ifodd\numexpr\r+\c\relax
      %...
```

Answer (score 3):

`\isodd` doesn't compute; you might do

```
\expandafter\ifthenelse\expandafter{\expandafter\NOT\expandafter\isodd\expandafter{\the\numexpr\r+\c}}
```

but it's not something I'd use myself. `;-)`

Here's a (non drop-in) reimplementation of `xifthen` allowing expressions; the syntax is different, though: for parentheses you use `(` and `)` rather than `\(` and `\)`. For the connectives, `\AND`, `\OR` and `\NOT` are replaced respectively by `&&`, `||` and `!`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % for the application

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_empty_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \blanktest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean     \legacy_if_p:n
\cs_new:Npn \modetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {h}{\mode_if_horizontal_p:}
    {v}{\mode_if_vertical_p:}
    {m}{\mode_if_math_p:}
    {i}{\mode_if_inner_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \enginetest #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {luatex}{\sys_if_engine_luatex_p:}
    {pdftex}{\sys_if_engine_pdftex_p:}
    {ptex}{\sys_if_engine_ptex_p:}
    {uptex}{\sys_if_engine_uptex_p:}
    {xetex}{\sys_if_engine_xetex_p:}
   }
   {\c_false_bool}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

1. \xifthenelse{\emptytest{}}{true}{false} true

2. \xifthenelse{\emptytest{ }}{true}{false} false

3. \xifthenelse{\emptytest{ foo }}{true}{false} false

4. \xifthenelse{\blanktest{}}{true}{false} true

5. \xifthenelse{\blanktest{ }}{true}{false} true

6. \xifthenelse{\numtest{10 * 10 + 1 > 100}}{true}{false} true

7. \xifthenelse{\numtest{10 * 10 + 1 > 100 * 100}}{true}{false} false

8. \xifthenelse{\eqdeftest{\usepackage}{\RequirePackage}}{true}{false} true

9. \xifthenelse{\eqdeftest{\usepackage}{\textit}}{true}{false} false

10. \xifthenelse{\namedeftest{@foo}}{true}{false} false

11. \xifthenelse{\namedeftest{@for}}{true}{false} true

12. \xifthenelse{\namedeftest{@for} || \numtest{1>2}}{true}{false} true

13. \xifthenelse{\namedeftest{@for} && \numtest{1>2}}{true}{false} false

14. \xifthenelse{\namedeftest{@for} && !\numtest{1>2}}{true}{false} true

15. \xifthenelse{!\oddtest{1+3}}{true}{false} true

16. \xifthenelse{\modetest{m}}{true}{false} false

17. $\xifthenelse{\modetest{m}}{true}{false}$ true

18. \parbox{2cm}{\xifthenelse{\modetest{v}}{true}{false}} true

19. \xifthenelse{\modetest{v}}{true}{false} false

20. \xifthenelse{\modetest{h}}{true}{false} true

21. \parbox{2cm}{\xifthenelse{\modetest{h}}{true}{false}} false

22. $\xifthenelse{\modetest{i}}{true}{false}$ true

23. \parbox{2cm}{\[\xifthenelse{\modetest{i}}{true}{false}\]} false

24. \xifthenelse{\fptest{22/7 = pi}}{true}{false} false

25. \xifthenelse{\enginetest{pdftex}}{true}{false} true

26. \xifthenelse{\enginetest{uptex}}{true}{false} false

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 10pt}]
  \foreach \r in {1, ..., 4} {
    \foreach \c in {1, ..., 5} {
      \xifthenelse{!\oddtest{\r+\c}}
      {\node (\r\c) [fill = lightgray] at (\c, \r){}}
      {\node (\r\c) at (\c, \r){}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, using PGF methods for the picture case is much easier.