# \ifthenelse command when using expl3 syntax

Tags: expl3, ifthenelse

What is the equivalent of `\ifthenelse{<statement>}{<iftrue>}{<iffalse>}` when using `expl3` syntax?

Comment: `expl3` has different conditional macros, such as `\bool_if:NTF \some_bool {true branch}{false branch}` or `\seq_if_in:NnTF` etc, depending on the 'variable' type and the precise application usage

Comment: Let's say I want to check whether two integers are equal or not, would something like `\bool_if:{ \equal{#1}{#2} }{ <iftrue> }{ <iffalse> }` work?

Comment: No, since integers are not bool, at least not that way. `\int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {#2} {true}{false}` -- the `\equal` etc. syntax is not available in `expl3` and I found `\ifthenelse` never convincing -- see the `interface3` manual please

Comment: You could do `\bool_if:nTF { \int_compare_p:nNn {#1} = {#2} } { true } { false }`, but as @ChristianHupfer says normally one would use just the basic `int` comparison.

Comment: @JosephWright: Is your style more efficient?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, quite the opposite, but it's using the general 'do some comparisons' syntax

Comment: @JosephWright: I seem to have missed `\int_compare_p:nNn` however yet -- most likely I had no need for it (yet)

Comment: You may want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467527/4427