# \ifthenelse do nothing

Tags: conditionals, tabularx, xifthen

I want to define a table as command. Some lines schould only be printed, if there is a value for it. Because of that I am using the `\ifthenelse` command.

Example:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
        \hline
        Titel & #1\\ \hline
        Caption & #2\\ \hline
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{Priority & #3\\ \hline}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{Members & #4\\ \hline}
\end{tabularx}
```

But there is a problem:
If I leve the seccond brackets of `\ifthenelse` empty, a space symbol i printed. Normaly you wouldn't see it. But the `tabularx` knows that there is a symbol and creates a new line for this symbols. Both packages `ifthen` and `xifthen` have this problem.

[image]

How to avoid, that `\ifthenelse` creates the space symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are better alternatives to `\ifthenelse` that don't have the problem.

Instead of `\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{<empty>}{<not empty>}` you can use

```
\ifstrempty{#3}{}{Priority & #3\\ \hline}
\ifstrempty{{#4}}{}{Members & #4\\ \hline}
```

This needs `\usepackage{etoolbox}`.

Another possibility:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467527/4427
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest \tl_if_blank_p:n
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \xxifthen_legacy_conditional:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \use:c { if#1 } \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean \xxifthen_legacy_conditional_p:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\ahrtable}[4]{%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
    \hline
    Title & #1\\ \hline
    Caption & #2\\ \hline
    \xifthenelse{\emptytest{#3}}{}{Priority & #3\\ \hline}
    \xifthenelse{\emptytest{#4}}{}{Members & #4\\ \hline}
  \end{tabularx}%
}


\begin{document}

\ahrtable{Title}{Caption}{}{}

\bigskip

\ahrtable{Title}{Caption}{Priority}{}

\bigskip

\ahrtable{Title}{Caption}{}{Members}

\bigskip

\ahrtable{Title}{Caption}{Priority}{Members}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

as no test document was supplied this is untested but basically you can do the tests before ending the previous line:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
        \hline
        Titel & #1\\ \hline
        Caption & #2%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\\ \hline Priority & #3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\\ \hline Members & #4}\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Yes it works if you do it like this. Thank you. But why does `\ithenelse` adds an space to an empty block?

Comment: @Ahrtaler it doesn't it is that if you use anything there (try `\relax` or `{}` for example) the tex starts processing a new cell in a new last line

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why the `\ifthenelse` expansion creates extra spaces on output, but it seems to be related to the fact that it isn't [fully expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros), i.e. uses assignments internally.

When you define a similar command `\ifequal` that actually does expand completely, the extra output is gone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand\ifequal[4]{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}=0 #3\else #4\fi}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
        \hline
        Titel & 1\\ \hline
        Caption & 2\\ \hline
        \ifequal{}{}{}{Priority & 3\\ \hline}
        \ifequal{}{}{}{Members & 4\\ \hline}
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
        \hline
        Titel & 1\\ \hline
        Caption & 2\\ \hline
        \ifequal{}{}{}{Priority & 3\\ \hline}
        \ifequal{y}{}{}{Members & 4\\ \hline}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The disadvantage of this approach is that you need to define several specialized commands for the various kinds of conditions.