# LaTeX `or` statements

Tags: conditionals

I need to test if one of multiple is defined. I know this command:

```
\ifIsDefined{\MYVAR}{
    % Do sometyhing
}
```

But, I need to test for two conditions like

> if A or B is defined, then do this

How can you do this?

.

Comment: If nothing else, `\ifA\doit\else\ifB\doit\else\fail\fi\fi`.  There are several packages to help with conditionals.  Are you open to using them?  What are the conditions that you want to test, and the actions that you want to take?

Comment: I am open to small libraries. I need to be able to execute the same code in two cases but not the third case.

Answer (score 2):

Use the package [ifthen](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) which is small to test if something is defined.

```
\ifthenelse{\(\NOT \isundefined{\MYVAR} \OR \NOT \isundefined{\MYSECONDVAR}\)}
{
    %True case
}
{
    % False case
}
```

See more examples here: https://riptutorial.com/latex/example/28656/if-statements

Answer (score 1):

Essentially no additional package, because `expl3` is now loaded in the LaTeX kernel. You could even dispense with `xparse` by doing

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\xifthenelse}[3]
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
```

in the first few lines, but I'd avoid it and prefer `xparse` for consistency. The code is drawn from [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467527/4427).

What's the difference with `\ifthenelse` from `ifthen`? That this new implementation has *fully expandable* tests. In the first argument of `\xifthen` you can use any of the defined tests linked together with `!` (for “not”), `&&` (for “and”) or `||` (for “or”) and normal parentheses.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \xxifthen_legacy_conditional:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \use:c { if#1 } \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean \xxifthen_legacy_conditional_p:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xifthenelse{ \deftest\MYVAR || \deftest\MYSECONDVAR }{%
  One of them is defined%
}{
  Neither is defined%
}

\newcommand\MYVAR{x}

\xifthenelse{ \deftest\MYVAR || \deftest\MYSECONDVAR }{%
  One of them is defined%
}{
  Neither is defined%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]