# nested test of a \def definition with \ifthenelse leads to "! Missing \endcsname inserted"

Tags: conditionals

I'm trying to make definitions from definitions (I don't know if this is how it should be called), here is an example (updated to make clear of my actual aim):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\street{num. 1, my street}
\def\block{my block}
\def\town{my town, my zipcode}
\def\state{my state}

\def\doordetails{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\street}{}}{}{\street}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\street}{} \or \equal{\street}{}}{}{, }%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\block}{}}{}{\block}}

\def\regiondetails{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\town}{}}{}{\town}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\town}{} \or \equal{\state}{}}{}{, }%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\state}{}}{}{\state}}


\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\doordetails}{}}{}{\doordetails}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\doordetails}{} \or \equal{\regiondetails}{}}{}{~~~\textbullet~~~}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\regiondetails}{}}{}{\regiondetails}}
\end{document}
```

But I get this error when trying building

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\let 
l.15 \ifthenelse{\equal{\doordetails}{}}{xxx}{xxx}
                                    \\%
```

Comment: that won't work. \ifthenelse is not expandable. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: `\ifthenelse` tests cannot be nested; you *can* use `\ifthenelse` in the “true” and “false“ branches, but not inside the test. Maybe some more details about your real aim can help in finding a way out.

Comment: i updated, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I don't think I would even use `ifthen` here. I'd use the tools from the `etoolbox` package, especially `\ifdefvoid`. I have a letter class where all the formatting is using this construction to see if a macro exists, is `\relax` or is "empty".

Answer (score 1):

You are using primitive `\def`, so you can use directly other related primitives and do not rely on LaTeX packages:

```
\def\street{num. 1, my street}
\def\block{my block}
\def\town{my town, my zipcode}
\def\state{my state}

\def\doordetails{%
  \street
  \ifx\relax\street\block\relax \else , \fi
  \block 
}
\def\regiondetails{%
  \town
  \ifx\relax\town\state\relax   \else , \fi
  \state
}

\doordetails
\ifx\relax\doordetails\regiondetails\relax\else ~~~$\bullet$~~~\fi
\regiondetails
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not have interpreted the OP's logic properly with regard to the text bullet (when to appear and when not), but the point is you can use simple `\if` and `\ifx` to address nested conditions.

When macro is either blank or filled, you use `\ifx\empty\<macro-name>` and if the macro expands to something or nothing, then use `\if\relax\<macro-name>\relax`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\street{num. 1, my street}
\def\block{my block}
\def\town{my town, my zipcode}
\def\state{my state}

\def\doordetails{%
  \ifx\street\empty
    \block
  \else
    \street
    \ifx\block\empty
    \else
      , \block
    \fi
  \fi
}

\def\regiondetails{%
  \ifx\town\empty
    \state
  \else
    \town
    \ifx\state\empty
    \else
      , \state
    \fi
  \fi
}

\def\alldetails{
\if\relax\doordetails\relax
  \regiondetails
\else
  \doordetails
  \if\relax\regiondetails\relax
  \else
    ~~~\textbullet~~~\regiondetails
  \fi
\fi}
\begin{document}
\alldetails

\def\street{}\alldetails

\def\town{}\alldetails

\def\block{}\alldetails

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest `\ifthenelse` calls.

Here's a replacement, but note some differences: `\or` should be `||` and parentheses should be used straight, not like `\(` and `\)` as is the case with `\ifthenelse`. The code is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546445/4427 with a few changes. These conditionals are fully expandable, so they can be nested.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \booleantest \legacy_if_p:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\doordetails{%
  \xifthenelse{\emptytest{\street}}{}{\street}%
  \xifthenelse{\emptytest{\street} || \emptytest{\block}}{}{, }%
  \xifthenelse{\emptytest{\block}}{}{\block}%
}

\newcommand\regiondetails{%
  \xifthenelse{\emptytest{\town}}{}{\town}%
  \xifthenelse{\emptytest{\town} || \emptytest{\state}}{}{, }%
  \xifthenelse{\emptytest{\state}}{}{\state}%
}


\begin{document}

\newcommand\street{num. 1, my street}
\newcommand\block{my block}
\newcommand\town{my town, my zipcode}
\newcommand\state{my state}

\xifthenelse{\emptytest{\doordetails}}{}{\doordetails}
\xifthenelse{\emptytest{\doordetails} || \emptytest{\regiondetails}}{}{~~~\textbullet~~~}%
\xifthenelse{\emptytest{\regiondetails}}{}{\regiondetails}

\end{document}
```

[image]