# On a conditional command: more powerful than \ifnum

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, foreach, ifthenelse

According to the [TEX in a Nutshell](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex-nutshell), Petr Olšák, page 16/29, we get:

> \ifnum ⟨number 1⟩ ⟨relation⟩ ⟨number 2⟩ . The ⟨relation⟩ could be < or
> = or >. It returns true if the comparison of the two numbers is true.

I am looking for a more powerful conditional command to include (~=) (not equal to) relation.

- Do we have such a conditional command?

The reason I asked is related to page 1005/1318 TikZ manual. Which I modified the code a little bit to generate an array of elliptical objects as below:

[image]

I rotated all ellipses 45 degree clockwise. What I want to do is not to rotate the highlighted ellipses in yellow so the `rot=0` for them.

- How to do it with a conditional command?

Below is my code:

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
\foreach \y in {1,...,4}

{
\fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt, y radius=6pt, rotate=-45];
\ifnum {\x<\y} & {\x>1}
\breakforeach
\fi
}
\draw [|-|] (.895,1) -- ++(0.211,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems ifthen package is the answer. I used  the code below using \ifthenelse, but got an error:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{1>2 \AND 3=3}{yes}{no}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
\foreach \y in {1,...,4}
{
\newcommand{\first}{\(\x=1 \and \y=1\)}
\newcommand{\second}{\(\x=2 \and \y=1\) }
\ifthenelse{\(\first\) \or \(\second\)}
 {\fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt , y radius= 6pt, rotate=0];}
{\fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt , y radius= 6pt, rotate=-45];}
\ifnum \x<\y
\breakforeach
\fi
}
\draw [|-|] (.895,1) -- ++(0.211,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error:
! Extra \or.
 ...=1) } \ifthenelse {(\first ) \or
(\second )} {\fill [red!...
Do you know how to debug this code to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to reproduce the picture, the test should be 1 ≤ x < y.

You can parametrize the rotation angle and test for the two special cases.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4} {
    \def\rotation{-45}
    \ifnum\y=1
      \ifnum\x=1 \def\rotation{0} \fi
      \ifnum\x=2 \def\rotation{0} \fi
    \fi
    \fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt, y radius=6pt, rotate=\rotation];
    \ifnum \x<\y \unless\ifnum \x<1 \breakforeach \fi\fi
  }
}
\draw [|-|] (.895,1) -- ++(0.211,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `\ifthenelse`, of course.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4} {
    \ifthenelse{\y=1 \AND \(\x=1 \OR \x=2\)}{\def\rotation{0}}{\def\rotation{-45}}
    \fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt, y radius=6pt, rotate=\rotation];
    \ifthenelse{ \x<\y \AND \NOT\(\x<1\) }{\breakforeach}{}
  }
}
\draw [|-|] (.895,1) -- ++(0.211,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With a somewhat easier syntax, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467527/4427

```latex
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \xxifthen_legacy_conditional:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \use:c { if#1 } \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean \xxifthen_legacy_conditional_p:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4} {
    \xifthenelse{\numtest{\y=1} && (\numtest{\x=1} || \numtest{\x=2})}
      {\def\rotation{0}}
      {\def\rotation{-45}}
    \fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt, y radius=6pt, rotate=\rotation];
    \xifthenelse{ \numtest{1<=\x<\y} }{\breakforeach}{}
  }
}
\draw [|-|] (.895,1) -- ++(0.211,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we do it with ifthenelse?

Comment: @Aria Is there any reason to? Anyway, I added it.

Comment: I thought if then else might be shorter.

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX's ifthen package has some facility for combining conditionals with `\and` and `\or`, `\not` and parentheses. But your case is easy to do with `\ifnum`:

```
\ifnum \x<\y \ifnum \x>1
  \breakforeach
\fi\fi
```

Comment: Can we get parentheses in \ifthenelse{(\x=1 \and \y=1) \or (\x=2 \and \y=1)}{<task1>}{<task2>}?

Comment: Do `texdoc ifthen`.  The introduction is all the documentation you need to read. Parentheses need to be `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: Got error for: \newcommand{\first}{\(\x=1 \and \y=1\)}
\newcommand{\second}{\(\x=2 \and \y=1\) }
\ifthenelse{\first \or \second }
 {\fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt , y radius= 6pt, rotate=0];}
{\fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt , y radius= 6pt, rotate=-45];}

Comment: I need to have a condition like (p and q) or (p and r), do you know how to define?

Comment: You can't hide the syntax in macros. You still have the wrong parentheses. My answer was for \ifnum anyway, rather than \ifthenelse. There may be other options with "expl" syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
\tikzmath {\xEnd=\x+1;}
\foreach \y in {1,...,\xEnd} {
\fill[red!50] (\x,\y) 
ellipse [x radius=3pt, y radius=6pt, rotate={ifthenelse(\x==1 || \x==2 && \y==1,0,-45)}];
}}
\draw [|-|] (.895,1) -- ++(0.211,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a much simpler solution. Below are the key ideas:

- `\ifthenelse` from [ifthen](https://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) package in CTAN is that powerful conditional command.
- `\ifthenelse{<test>}{<then clause>}{<else clause>}`is the command format wherein `<test>` is a boolean expression using the infix connectives, `\and`, `\or`, the unary
  `\not` and parentheses `\( \)`.
- Also `\OR` and `\AND` are safer to be used with `\ifthenelse` rather than using `\or` and `\and`since it can’t be misinterpreted when appearing inside a TEX-conditional in which `\or` has a different meaning.
  So here is the code:

  ```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
  {
  \ifthenelse{\(\x=1 \AND \y=1\) \OR \(\x=2 \AND \y=1\) }
  {\fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt , y radius= 6pt, rotate=0];}
  {\fill[red!50] (\x,\y) ellipse [x radius=3pt , y radius= 6pt, rotate=-45];}
  \ifnum \x<\y
  \breakforeach
  \fi
  }
   \draw [|-|] (.895,1) -- ++(0.211,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]