# How can I change text, depending on whether it is \scshape or not?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, sectioning, conditionals, small-caps

What would be the simplest way to create a macro like `\ifscshape{sc case}{else}` (similar to e.g. `\ifdraft{}{}`), so that this

```
\newcommand{\cec}{\ifscshape{CEC}{\textsc{Cec}}}

In normal text, the acronym \cec{} should be printed in small caps.

\textsc{But if surrounded by small caps, \cec{} should be printed in uppercase.}
```

would output something like this

[image]

similarly to how `\emph` interacts with italics?

---

#### Edit:

I tried to use `\scacronym` (an adaptation from @TiMauzi's macro in their answer), which works like a charm in regular text, but breaks inside titles.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{microtype,xspace,libertine}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\lsstyle}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scacronym}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\f@shape}{sc}}{\uppercase{#1}}{\textsc{#1}}\xspace}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Shapes \& Types of \scacronym{Cec}}
    
    In normal text, the acronym \scacronym{Cec} should be printed in small caps.\\
    \textsc{But if surrounded by small caps, \scacronym{Cec} should be printed in uppercase.}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this, I get a huge number of similar errors, <del>some shown below</del>. What's happening here and how can I fix this?

---

#### Edit 2:

@TiMauzi's updated solution using `etoolbox` solved above issue:

[image]

However, if this macro should apply in the TOC entries and headers/footers, it's better to define it using `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\scacronym}[1]{%
    \ifdefstring{\f@shape}{sc}{\uppercase{#1}}{\textsc{#1}}\xspace}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Does your document employ only `\textsc`, or does it also employ `\scshape`?

Comment: In my specific document, I would need it to work only with ``\scshape`` actually. I need the uppercase variant in chapter titles, that are formatted with ``\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\lsstyle}``. I did not think that would make a difference, so I used ``\textsc`` for limiting the scope of ``sc``.

Comment: I added an alternative approach to both my first solution and your solution, using the `\etoolbox` package.

Comment: @TiMauzi That solved the issue in the headings, thank you! Have you tried compiling in pdfLaTeX? It works fine for me. XeLaTeX can't handle ``\lsstyle``, so that's expected to fail. One last thing: The ``etoolbox`` solution somehow doesn't do it's job in my ``\scshape``d TOC entries though, and prints 'Cec' not 'CEC'. Any ideas on that? If not, maybe I should post a follow-up... But your answer definitely answers the original question, so thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifscshape}[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\f@shape}{sc}}{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\cec}{\ifscshape{\uppercase{Cec}}{\textsc{Cec}}}

\begin{document}
In normal text, the acronym \cec{} should be printed in small caps.

\textsc{But if surrounded by small caps, \cec{} should be printed in uppercase.}
\end{document}
```

I used the package `ifthen` here, comparing `\f@shape` (with the current font shape as output) to the string `sc` by using the `\equal` command. Within your text, you should put `{}` after the `\cec` command, so a space is placed after your emphasized text.

*Note:* Within the command `\ifscshape`, I changed your original first argument `CEC` to `\uppercase{Cec}` for better presentation and distinction from `\textsc`. It works either way, though.

**Edit 1:**

If the command should be working within sectioning commands, the usage of the package `etoolbox` is the better alternative:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifscshape}[2]{%
    \ifdefstring{\f@shape}{sc}{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\cec}{\ifscshape{CEC}{\textsc{Cec}}}

\begin{document}
\section{The Acronym \cec}
This is the section's content using \cec{} or \textsc{also \cec}.
\end{document}
```

Instead of `\ifthenelse`, the command `\ifdefstring` is used, comparing the content of a command to a given string. In general, this approach seems to be more stable than the approach with the `\ifthen` package. Of course, a small caps variant should be supported by the used section font.

**Edit 2:**

Adjusting the second solution to the second MWE of @schoekling, the following should work:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{microtype,xspace,libertine}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\lsstyle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scacronym}[1]{%
    \ifdefstring{\f@shape}{sc}{\uppercase{#1}}{\textsc{#1}}\xspace}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Shapes \& Types of \scacronym{Cec}}
    
    In normal text, the acronym \scacronym{Cec} should be printed in small caps.\\
    \textsc{But if surrounded by small caps, \scacronym{Cec} should be printed in uppercase.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output for the 3rd MWE.]

*Note:* This approach seems to work if the document is compiled with LuaLaTeX, but not with e.g. XeLaTeX or PDFLaTeX.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! :D I originally forgot about the ``{}`` because I used ``\xspace`` in my original document, whoops. I also just realized I could make the macro more ``emph``-like and skip the whole ``\cec`` step by modifying your macro to ``\newcommand{\scacronym}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\f@shape}{sc}}{\uppercase{#1}}{\textsc{#1}}\xspace}``. Thanks!

Comment: @schoekling To be honest, I first had your "modified" answer in mind. I changed it, so it fits your definition better - but you figured out my original approach myself perfectly then.

Comment: Edit: You figured out my original approach *yourself*, of course :)

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I got excited there too early... The macro doesn't work in sectioning commands, any idea why?

Comment: @schoekling Can you please provide an example for this use case?

Comment: Already added a MWE to my question.

Comment: @schoekling It seems like the `\ifthen` package isn't as stable as e.g. the `\etoolbox` package when it comes to usages outside of plain texts. See this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13867/205359

Comment: Note that there are occasional pitfalls around the various `\f@` macros lurking. Sometimes the command is defined with `\newcommand` and sometimes with `\newcommand*`, sometimes a `\@empty` will be added to the definition. I dealt with a similar issue in March and ended up creating commands (using `xparse` and expl3 syntax which I wrote about at https://www.preppylion.com/identifying-the-current-font/