# Is the ifthen package not recommended to use?

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox

I've seen several posts and users recommend avoiding the `ifthen` package, however, I see it was recently updated (2020).

One feature I'm trying to exploit from it is an expanded string comparison. `etoolbox` offers unexpanded string comparison via `\ifstrequal` (I suppose the intention is to use this in macros to check argument strings?), or it can expand a string in the first argument (only one expansion?) via `\ifdefstring`. My needs would require full expansion, say for concatenating two definitions. Please see MWE below

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% \newcommand{\ifstringeqx}[4]{% will not work in section here, use robust cmd
\newrobustcmd{\ifstringeqx}[4]{%
\ifthenelse%
    {\equal{#1}{#2}}%
    {#3}%
    {#4}%
}


\begin{document}

\def\hello{Hi}
\def\world{Earth}

\section{\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{HiEarth}{Yes}{No}}

\def\world{Saturn}
\def\planet{Saturn}
\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{Hi\planet}{Yes}{No}

\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{HiJupiter}{Yes}{No}

\end{document}
```

10 year old post: [Why is the ifthen package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete)

Comment: ifthen is not expandable.

Comment: As far as I can see the code hasn't changed. The only changes in the file are the copyright statements, since the package is part of `base`.

Comment: apart from documentation updates there was one minor code change in 2001 but other than that it's unchanged since I made the latex2e version in 1993, (using the syntax of an old 2.09 file but a new implementation) but I don't think I have ever used it in all that time.

Comment: look at the `\pdfstrcmp` pdftex primitive for the stated use case

Comment: Thank you for the accepted answer.  Please see my **SUPPLEMENT** for more generality, if your Yes/No actions grow more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David's suggestion satisfies all the requirements. `\pdfstrcmp` expands its arguments before comparison and is itself expandable.

Note the implementation is engine specific and so an extra package needs loading if lualatex is used.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% WORKS FOR LUA + XELATEX + PDFLATEX ENGINES
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\let\strcmp\pdf@strcmp
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%% WORKS ONLY FOR PDFLATEX AND XELATEX ENGINES
%\let\strcmp\pdfstrcmp
%%%%%%%%%%%%% END

\newcommand{\ifstringeqx}[4]{%
    \ifnum\strcmp{#1}{#2}=0 #3\else#4\fi
}
\begin{document}
\def\hello{Hi}
\def\world{Earth}

\section{\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{HiEarth}{Yes}{No}}

\def\world{Saturn}
\def\planet{Saturn}
\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{Hi\planet}{Yes}{No}

\edef\isitexpandable{\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{HiJupiter}{Yes}{No}}

---$>$ \isitexpandable
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

If one is concerned with the `\else` and/or `\fi` in the definition of `\ifstringeqx` getting in the way of `#3` and `#4` doing their thing (for example, if they need to absorb tokens located beyond the `\fi`), we can copy/paste a little bit of logic from the `tokcycle` package to perform the `\ifnum` while removing the influence of `\else` and `\fi`:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\tctestifnum#1{\tctestifcon{\ifnum#1\relax}}
\long\def\tctestifcon#1{#1\expandafter\tc@exfirst\else\expandafter\tc@exsecond\fi}
\long\def\tc@exfirst#1#2{#1}
\long\def\tc@exsecond#1#2{#2}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ifstringeqx}[4]{%
    \tctestifnum{\strcmp{#1}{#2}=0}{#3}{#4}}
```

Here's an example where the original definition with `\else` and `\fi` won't work, but this revised definition works fine.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% WORKS FOR LUA + XELATEX + PDFLATEX ENGINES
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\let\strcmp\pdf@strcmp
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%% WORKS ONLY FOR PDFLATEX AND XELATEX ENGINES
%\let\strcmp\pdfstrcmp
%%%%%%%%%%%%% END

\makeatletter
\long\def\tctestifnum#1{\tctestifcon{\ifnum#1\relax}}
\long\def\tctestifcon#1{#1\expandafter\tc@exfirst\else\expandafter\tc@exsecond\fi}
\long\def\tc@exfirst#1#2{#1}
\long\def\tc@exsecond#1#2{#2}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ifstringeqx}[4]{%
    \tctestifnum{\strcmp{#1}{#2}=0}{#3}{#4}}


\def\Yes#1{#1 yes!}
\def\No#1{#1 no!}
\begin{document}
\def\hello{Hi}
\def\world{Earth}

\section{\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{HiEarth}{\Yes}{\No}{Hell}}

\def\world{Saturn}
\def\planet{Saturn}
\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{Hi\planet}{Yes}{No}

\edef\isitexpandable{\ifstringeqx{\hello\world}{HiJupiter}{\Yes}{\No}{Absolutely}}

---$>$ \isitexpandable
\end{document}
```

[image]