# Precedence of \and and \or

Tags: ifthenelse

I am using the ifthen package.  I see some comments on the web that there is a more recent alternative, so maybe the answer to this is, I should switch.  But in any event . . .

So if I have an expression like

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{boolval1} \and \boolean{boolval2} \or 
   \boolean{boolval3}}{\something}{\somethingelse}
```

it seems this is interpreted as

If ((boolval1 and boolval2) or boolval3) then something else somethingelse

However, what I want is

If (boolval1 and (boolval2 or boolval3)) then something else somethingelse

Including the boolval2 and boolval3 tests within curly braces { } generates an error.  Including them within parenthesis generates no error, but also seems to have no effect.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I haven't been able to find anything through U of Google.  There are multiple methods of workaround, so I can definitely do what I want, it's just cumbersome - I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Many thanks for any answers forthcoming . . .

Comment: See [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764)

Comment: you could check the documentation - it mentions on the first page how to input parentheses.

Comment: Are you actually using package `xifthen` ? Which compiler?