Condition IF in Tikz
I would like to draw a Riemann sums plot where the bars are graphed based on the heights of each pair of consecutive intervals. The issue will be with the ifthenelse statement as I do not think the logic statements are written correctly. I think either the sine values are not evaluated correctly or the conditional statements are not correct. Thank you for any help you can give.
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1.5]
        % axis
        \draw [<->] (0,-1.25) -- (0,1.25);
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- ({5*pi/3+0.25},0);
        % labelled tick marks
        \foreach \x/\p in {1/{$\frac{\pi}{3}$},2/{$\frac{2\pi
{3}$},3/{$\pi$},4/{$\frac{4\pi}{3}$},5/{$\frac{5\pi}{3}$}}
            {
                \ifthenelse{\x<3}
                    {\draw ({\x*pi/3},0) -- ({\x*pi/3},-0.1) node [below] {\p};}
                    {
                        \ifthenelse{\x>3}
                        {\draw ({\x*pi/3},0) -- ({\x*pi/3},0.1) node [above] {\p};}
                    }
            }
         % sine curve
         \draw [domain=0:{5*pi/3},->] plot (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
 %Riemann sums
         \foreach \x in {1,3,...,9}{
            % if midpoint value is posative
            \ifthenelse{ {sin(deg(\x*pi/6))}>0 }
            {
                % if midpoint value > next midpoint value
                \ifthenelse{ {sin(deg(\x*pi/6))}>sin{(deg((\x+2)*pi/6))} }
                {
                        % draw top of bar and down to x axis
                        \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/3,{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))}) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))})  -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,0);
                }{
                        % draw top of bar
                        \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/3,{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))}) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))})
                }
            }
         \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}


There are several problems with your code.

You are missing closing curly brackets in several places.
You provide only two of the three required arguments to \ifthenelse at times.
The result of the pgfmath parsing is a macro rather than a number, so it cannot be immediately utilised in tests by \ifthenelse (unless you treat it as non-numerical).
\ifthenelse is not expandable. That probably doesn't matter here (at least for the first loop), but it tends to give pgf/tikz indigestion and I'd try to avoid using it in these contexts. Better to use either the newer stuff based on expl3 or the lower level TeX conditional tests.

While it is not really a problem as such, ifthen is now deprecated. That is, there are better ways to do what it does in almost (but not all) cases. LaTeX itself now provides \fpeval and \inteval, along with functions to do comparisons. Since I can't seem to find any 2e interfaces for the comparisons, I provide simple wrappers for each in the code below. This is a bit clunky in terms of interface, but gets the job done.
I've also tried to minimise pgfmath calculations as these are very slow. You could hand the calculations over to \fpeval/\inteval, though I've not done that here. However, I have reused results to avoid running the same calculation with pgfmath multiple times.
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfDecimalTF \fp_compare:nNnTF
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfIntegerTF \int_compare:nNnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1.5]
  % axis
  \draw [<->] (0,-1.25) -- (0,1.25);
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- ({5*pi/3+0.25},0);
  % labelled tick marks
  \foreach \p [count=\x,evaluate=\x as \m using (\x*pi/3)] in
  {%
    {$\frac{\pi}{3}$},%
    {$\frac{2\pi}{3}$},%
    {$\pi$},%
    {$\frac{4\pi}{3}$},%
    {$\frac{5\pi}{3}$}%
  }
  {
    \IfIntegerTF {\x} < {3}
    {\draw (\m,0) -- (\m,-0.1) node [below] {\p};}
    {
      \IfIntegerTF {\x} > {3}
      {\draw (\m,0) -- (\m,0.1) node [above] {\p};}
      {}
    }
  }
  % sine curve
  \draw [domain=0:{5*pi/3},->] plot (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
  %Riemann sums
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \k using sin(deg((\x+2)*pi/6)),evaluate=\x as \j using sin(deg(\x*pi/6))] in {1,3,...,9}
  {
    % if midpoint value is posative
    \IfDecimalTF {\j} > { 0 }
    {
      % if midpoint value > next midpoint value
      \IfDecimalTF { \j } > { \k }
      {
        % draw top of bar and down to x axis
        \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/3,\j) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,\j)  -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,0);
      }{
        % draw top of bar
        \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/3,\j) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,\j);
      }
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I don't know what it is meant to look like as I only studied Lebesgue integration and there don't seem to be any step functions here ;). But here's the result:


Note that you may stick to \ifthenelse if you prefer, but I wish to avoid its author's wrath. ;)

I was informed by @cfr that ifthen is considered deprecated and isn't recommended for new code. It is not obsolete.
Since you are using tikz, it would make sense to use its built-in \pgfmathparse and \ifnum
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [<->] (0,-1.25) -- (0,1.25);
\draw [->] (0,0) -- ({5*pi/3+0.25},0);

\foreach \x/\p in 
{
    1/{$\frac{\pi}{3}$}
    ,2/{$\frac{2\pi}{3}$}
    ,3/{$\pi$}
    ,4/{$\frac{4\pi}{3}$}
    ,5/{$\frac{5\pi}{3}$}
}
{
    \pgfmathparse{\x<3}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \draw ({\x*pi/3},0) -- ({\x*pi/3},-0.1) node [below] {\p};
    \else
        \pgfmathparse{\x>3}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \draw ({\x*pi/3},0) -- ({\x*pi/3},0.1) node [above] {\p};
        \fi
    \fi
}

\draw [domain=0:{5*pi/3},->] plot (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});

\foreach \x in 
{1,3,...,9}
{
    \pgfmathparse{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))>0}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathparse{ sin(deg(\x*pi/6))>sin((deg((\x+2)*pi/6))) }
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/3,{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))}) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))})  -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,0);
        \else
                \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/3,{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))}) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/3,{sin(deg(\x*pi/6))});
        \fi
    \fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



The last version of ifthen : 2024/03/16. This doesn't look obsolete. :-)

@projectmbc Really? Let me read the doc again.

@projetmbc You are correct, I must just be remembering https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete

This is really @cfr solution. I just filled in the gaps so it did exactly what I wanted.
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfDecimalTF \fp_compare:nNnTF
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfIntegerTF \int_compare:nNnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1.5]
  % axis
   \draw [<->] (0,-1.25) -- (0,1.25);
   \draw [->] (0,0) -- ({5*pi/3+0.25},0);
   % labelled tick marks
   \foreach \p [count=\x,evaluate=\x as \m using (\x*pi/3)] in
   {%
    {$\frac{\pi}{3}$},%
    {$\frac{2\pi}{3}$},%
    {$\pi$},%
    {$\frac{4\pi}{3}$},%
    {$\frac{5\pi}{3}$}%
   }
  {
    \IfIntegerTF {\x} < {3}
    {\draw (\m,0) -- (\m,-0.1) node [below] {\p};}
    {
      \IfIntegerTF {\x} > {3}
      {\draw (\m,0) -- (\m,0.1) node [above] {\p};}
      {}
    }
  }
  % sine curve
  \draw [domain=0:{5*pi/3+0.25},->] plot (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
  %Riemann sums
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \k using      sin(deg((\x+2)*pi/6)),evaluate=\x as \j using sin(deg(\x*pi/6))] in           {1,3,...,9}
  {
     % draw dashed middle values
    \draw [dashed] (\x*pi/6,0) -- (\x*pi/6,\j);
    % if midpoint value is posative
     \IfDecimalTF {\j} > { 0 }
        {
            % if midpoint value > next midpoint value
            \IfDecimalTF { \j } > { \k }
            {
                    \IfDecimalTF {\k} > { 0 }% draw top of bar and     down to x axis
                    {
                 \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/6,\j) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\j)  --     (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,0);
             }{
                 \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/6,\j) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\j)  --      {\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\k);
             }
             }{ % { \j } <= { \k }
                    % draw top of bar
                     \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/6,\j) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\j);
                 \draw (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\k) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,0);
            }
        }{
            % if midpoint value > next midpoint value
            \IfDecimalTF { \j } < { \k }
            {
                    \IfDecimalTF {\k} < { 0 }% draw top of bar and     down to x axis
                    {
                 \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/6,\j) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\j)  --     (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,0);
            }{
                \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/6,\j) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\j)  --     (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\k);
            }
             }{ % { \j } <= { \k }
                     % draw top of bar
                    \draw (\x*pi/6 - pi/6,\j) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\j);
                \draw (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,\k) -- (\x*pi/6 + pi/6,0);
            }
    }
  }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}

