# Create a table with two parts with different tabular features

Tags: tables, formatting

I'm trying to build a table that has two panels with different numbers of columns. For example:

```
Table 1: An interesting table

           Panel A: Some stuff
First name      Last name       Product
Bubba           Gump            Shrimp
Steve           Jobs            Happiness

            Panel B: Other stuff
School       State
Harvard      MA
Yale         CT
Brown        RI
```

I would like the 3 columns of Panel A and the 2 columns of Panel B to fill the horizontal space of the table.

I imagined using two different \tabular commands within a \table would work, but it doesn't. I also found the `subfigure` package, but I think that only lets you stack tables horizontally, not vertically.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The `subfigure` package lets you stack tables vertically, for example by placing a \\ or `\par` between the `\subfigure`s.

Comment: I wouldn't spread the columns across the entire `\textwidth`, that looks terrible. Just compare the output of Stefan's solution (not spread) with Werner's's (spread). Using the `booktabs` package is a good idea though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Within a table environment, you can use different tabular environments, of different types and with a different number of columns. Here's an example with sub captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{An interesting table}
\subcaption*{Panel A: Some stuff}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
First name & Last name  & Product \\
Bubba & Gump & Shrimp \\
Steve & Jobs & Happiness
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\subcaption*{Panel B: Other stuff}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
School & State \\
Harvard & MA \\
Yale & CT \\
Brown & RI
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: sub tables example]

Here I used the [`subcaption`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) packages. A good alternative is the [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package. However, the [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package is [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/how-to-keep-up-with-packages-and-know-which-ones-are-obsolete).

Answer (score 4):

With liberal use of the `\multicolumn{.}{.}{...}` command, you can get away with spreading the table across the entire `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{An interesting table}
  \label{tbl:interesting}

  \begin{tabular}{*{6}{p{.16\linewidth}}}
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A: Some stuff} \\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.33\linewidth}}{First name} & \multicolumn{2}{p{.33\linewidth}}{Last name} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{p{.33\linewidth}}{Product} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Bubba} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Gump} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Shrimp} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Steve} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Jobs} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Happiness} \\
    \bottomrule
    \\
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B: Other stuff} \\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{p{.49\linewidth}}{School} & \multicolumn{3}{p{.49\linewidth}}{State} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{Harvard} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{MA} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{Yale} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{CT} \\ 
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{Brown} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{RI} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Since the two panels are contained in the same `tabular`, they span the same width. The above uses the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for presentation of the `tabular` environments. However, it is not necessarily needed. If you want to drop it, you should also drop/replace the `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` rules with `\hline` or another preference.

[image: Tables using multicolumn]

Alternatively, you could also use the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to spread columns across a specific width:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{An interesting table}
  \label{tbl:interesting}

  \medskip

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X X X }
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Panel A: Some stuff} \\
    \toprule
    First name & Last name & Product \\
    \midrule
    Bubba & Gump & Shrimp \\
    Steve & Jobs & Happiness \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X X }
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Panel B: Other stuff} \\
    \toprule
    School & State \\
    \midrule
    Harvard & MA \\
    Yale & CT \\ 
    Brown & RI \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tables using tabularx]

Comment: how did you get that value: `\begin{tabular}{*{6}{p{.16\linewidth}}}` ? 1/6 = 0.166, so it cannot be that.

Comment: @ghx: I wanted to set the `tabular` within the `\linewidth`, and for 6 columns to fit, I used 1/6 of `\linewidth` for each, or `0.16\linewidth`.

Comment: thanks I understand that, but isn't 1/6 = 0.1667 (rounded)? So I wonder how this ends up precise.

Comment: @ghx: Yes, 1/6 ~ 0.1667, but in `*{6}{p{.16\linewidth}}` there are 6 columns and 12 `\tabcolsep`s that also need to be considered: One on either side of the `tabular`'s outer columns, and 2 `\tabcolsep`s between each column pair (there are 5 of those). I rounded 1/6 down to 0.16 to allow for these to also fit within the `\linewidth`. Similarly for `.33\linewidth` when dealing with 3 columns and `.49\linewidth` for 2 columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`multicol`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/help/Catalogue/entries/multicol.html) column package to have data span multiple columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Panel A: Some stuff}\\
First name      &Last name       &Product\\
Bubba           &Gump            &Shrimp\\
Steve           &Jobs            &Happiness\\
\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Panel B: Other stuff}\\
School       &State\\
Harvard      &MA\\
Yale         &CT\\
Brown        &RI\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need a different approach. I want the 2 columns in panel B to span just as much space as the 3 columns in panel A. This table has a 3rd (blank) column in panel B, which I am trying not to have.

Comment: You can use the `\multicolumn` macro to adjust that. For example you can use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{State}` to have that column span the two columns.  If I am still not understanding please provide a more detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this?

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\multicolumn{ 3}{c}{Panel A: Some stuff} \\
\hline
First name &  Last name &    Product \\
\hline
     Bubba &       Gump &     Shrimp \\
\hline
     Steve &       Jobs &   Happines \\
\hline
\multicolumn{ 3}{c}{Panel B: Other stuff} \\
\hline
    School & \multicolumn{ 2}{l}{State} \\
\hline
   Harvard & \multicolumn{ 2}{l}{CT} \\
\hline
      Yale & \multicolumn{ 2}{l}{CI} \\
\hline
     Brown & \multicolumn{ 2}{l}{RI} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```