# Extending bottomrule when using two tabular in table

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am wanting to vertically stack two tables, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26351/create-a-table-with-two-parts-with-different-tabular-features) by Stefan. I am wanting to include a `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` to enclose the entirety of the table (both tabulars).

The problem I get is that the `\toprule` is the width of the columns of tabular one, and `\bottomrule` is the width of the second tabular.

Modifying the code used from the above link (to use the packages only relevant to me), this is how I am trying to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{An interesting table}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
\toprule
First name & Last name  & Product \\
Bubba & Gump & Shrimp \\
Steve & Jobs & Happiness
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ll}
School & State \\
Harvard & MA \\
Yale & CT \\
Brown & RI \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example it's possible to use an outer `tabular` that spreads out the width of the other tables using `@{}c@{}` as column specifier applying `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` for the outer table, then putting the other two `tabular` environments inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{An interesting table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
First name & Last name  & Product \\
Bubba & Gump & Shrimp \\
Steve & Jobs & Happiness
\end{tabular} \\ 
\midrule[0pt] % Empty midrule which adds vertical spacing anyway above and below but is not drawn itself
\begin{tabular}{ll}
School & State \\
Harvard & MA \\
Yale & CT \\
Brown & RI
\end{tabular} \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks work beautifully, one question is there any reason for using `\\ ` before the `\midrule[0pt]` and `\tabularnewline` before the `\bottomrule`. As far as I can tell they are doing identical things so why the difference?

Comment: `\tabularnewline` is more outstanding (easier to recognize) -- I always use `\tabularnewline` in my own code, but do not change in foreign code ;-)