# Hyphenation for mixed language document

Tags: languages, hyphenation

I'm currently writing my Bachelor's thesis in English but have to include a German abstract. Hyphenation will not work for German words unless I include the `ngerman` package. But then English words are not hyphenated.

Is there a way to switch the language for a specific chapter only?

Comment: As mentioned in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/how-to-keep-up-with-packages-and-know-which-ones-are-obsolete, `ngerman` is considered obsolete, using the `babel` package with the `ngerman` option is better (as Herbert did in his answer).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}% the last in the list is the active one
...

Some english text ...

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
Etwas deutscher Text ...

\selectlanguage{english}
...
```