# Bullets not showing in beamer

Tags: beamer

I copied a presentation in which everything worked fine, and now in this new presentation there are no bullets showing on slide!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,hyperref={breaklinks=true},mathserif,professionalfont,12pt]{beamer} 
\usecolortheme[named=RoyalBlue]{structure} 
\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester} 
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball] 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{time}
\usepackage{extarrows}


\title{Random title}
\subtitle{Random subtitle}
\author{Random Randofsky}
\institute{Random institute, Random City 1000, Randomia}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{Random section1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{About}
\begin{itemize}
\item Random stuff Random stuff
\item \itshape{more random stuff}
\item Random stuff...
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reference}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
Thank you for listening\\

The End
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What seems to be the problem? I didn't change anything in the preamble.

Comment: Look fine to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GOnwY.png. Maybe it is an local install issue. Try to update your installation.

Comment: Did you try this MWE besides your original code? I can see the bullets on the second slide.

Comment: Yeah I tried with this code... Weird. And the weirder stuff is that the other presentation works fine :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** The problem based on the compilation. [dingo_d](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4682/dingo-d) uses `dvipdfm`. By changing to `pdflatex` everything works well.

---

I have no problem with your example.

Some packages of your header are obsolote. Have a look at this post:
[How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/how-to-keep-up-with-packages-and-know-which-ones-are-obsolete)

You don't need to load `color` and `xcolor` together (In `beamer` the package will be load by default).

Maybe there is a problem with you versions. Here my file list:

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2011/09/12 development version 3.12 A class for typesetting pre
sentations (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbasercs.sty    2011/09/21 (rcs-revision 42a2c9debdc3)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2010/04/27 (rcs-revision 982469101dd6)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
hyperref.sty    2011/10/01 v6.82j Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Subsetting bundle oberdiek (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/04/04 v1.12 Provides string conversions (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Data type bit set (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/01/30 v1.0 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/04/23 v1.7 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/01/30 v1.15 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2010/12/01 v3.2 Data extraction from references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2011/10/01 v6.82j Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2011/10/01 v6.82j Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2010/07/12  (rcs-revision 6648c3177e4e)
beamerbasefont.sty    2010/10/26  (rcs-revision f39336aafb3c)
 amssymb.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00
amsfonts.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision bff0a9294b45)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2010/08/29  (rcs-revision e07e85b4cd4a)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 242ecaa6783b)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2010/09/19  (rcs-revision 9224c5f3ce70)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2009/07/02 v2.20.1
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemestructure.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty    2010/07/10  (rcs-revision 445340293dde)
beamerthemeRochester.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemesidebar.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerectangles.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemeprofessionalfonts.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)

mathtools.sty    2011/04/06 v1.11 mathematical typesetting tools
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2010/01/21 v1.2a programming setup (MH)
     bbm.sty    1999/03/15 V 1.2 provides fonts for set symbols - TH
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
croatian.ldf    2005/03/29 v1.3l Croatian support from the babel system
     ucs.sty    2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode input support
uni-global.def    2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode global data
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
   utf8x.def    2004/10/17 UCS: Input encoding UTF-8
 txfonts.sty    2008/01/22 v3.2.1
subfigure.sty    2002/03/15 v2.1.5 subfigure package
subfigure.cfg
listings.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
    time.sty    
extarrows.sty    2008/05/15 v1.0b Some extensible arrows
 omltxmi.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
 omstxsy.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
 omxtxex.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
  utxexa.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
 ot1txss.fd    2000/12/15 v3.1
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
    test.out
    test.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
 ucsencs.def    2003/11/29 Fixes to fontencodings LGR, T3
 ***********
```

[image]

Comment: I know it is more a comment so I answered as community wiki.

Comment: I really dk what's the problem. I updated everything, including beamer and still I don't get bullets :\

Comment: @dingo_d: Which viewer do you used? Sometimes (really sometimes) it depends on the viewer.

Comment: Well I compile it and view in Adobe Acrobat...
EDIT: Ok I found out the problem. If I compile it via dvipdfm the bullets won't show. But if I compile it with PDFLaTeX it works (.eps figures won't show, but that's a minor setback)...

Comment: @dingo_d: To use eps-figures you can load the package epstopdf. (or you can try latex-ps-pdf via dvips->ps2pdf)

Comment: Yup, I do that now. I compile via latex, and then in cmd manually first dvips and then ps2pdf. Works like a charm xD

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar problem using XeLaTex, and it turned out the reason was an incompatibility with the *enumitem* package.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that removing enumitem (which I had imported from my paper, but wasn't necessary for my presentation) resolved my issue.

Comment: This was my problem too, and I'm not using XeLaTex.

Comment: This was my problem, and I've used pdfLaTeX. Thanks for pointing that out !