# \citep does not work using natbib package

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

The `\citep` command does not display the author and year, instead it displays a number.

This is the head file.

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}

\usepackage{natbib} % various citation commands
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

This is the end, references are stored in DM.bib

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{DM}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? I want to cite author and year, but not just a number.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fragments are not very helpful. I create a minimal example which produced the result seen in the picture below.

---

Most of your loaded packages are obsolete.

Some obsolete packages are collected in the Q&A:
[How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/how-to-keep-up-with-packages-and-know-which-ones-are-obsolete)

In your case the packages:
`times`, `a4wide`, `fancyheadings`, `epsfig`

If you had an old LaTeX-installation you should install TeXLive 2011.

---

Now the example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Mustermann,
 author = {Mustermann, A. and Mostermann, B. and Mistermann, C},
 year = {2011},
 title = {Using articles in {\LaTeX} documents},
 journal = {Journal}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{document} 
\cite{Mustermann}\qquad\citet{Mustermann}\qquad\citep{Mustermann}

\citeyear{Mustermann}\qquad\citeauthor{Mustermann}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: The **filecontents** package is not necessary, if you put the `filecontents` environments before `\documentclass`.

Comment: @egreg: Without the package the generate file will no be overridden. (I hope it is correct `;-)` )

Comment: Yes, the standard `filecontents` doesn't overwrite existing files (which is usually what one wants, as in this case). If you use it for having the bibliography database in the main document, then use the package, but loading it normally and using the environment after `\documentclass`. I believe it's easier than using the non standard `\RequirePackage` command.

Comment: @egreg: I changed my code. Thanks for the information.

Comment: For a more simple MWE you could use `\bibliography{biblatex-examples}`