# \storeglosentry --> Undefined control sequence

Tags: glossaries, mactex, texshop

I am trying to write a report for school in LaTeX. Therefore I am using MacTeX and Texshop and normally it works pretty fine.

But at the moment I have some trouble with the `glossary` package:

```
\usepackage[style=long,border=plain,header=plain,cols=3,hyper=true]{glossary}
\makeglossary
```

when I use

```
\glossary{name={entry name},description={entry description}}
```

I get no errors and the glossary is printed right. But when I use

```
\storeglosentry{label}{{entry name},description={entry description}}

\useGlosentry{label}{Text}
```

I get the error

> Undefined control sequence.

Do you have any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The command `\storeglosentry` has been added in `glossary` version 2.17. From the CHANGES file:

> ```
> * Version 2.17: added acronym package option. Added 
>   \storeglosentry (replacing old \saveglosentry command)
> ```

And from `glossaries.dtx`:

> ```
> %\changes{2.17}{2005 June 28}{'storeglosentry added}
> ```

So your `glossary` version is probably too old. If you would like to use that command, updating to 2.17 or later would solve that.

However, `glossary` is obsolete. I strongly recommend to update to its successor [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), written by the same author. That's better than trying to fix problems with an outdated package which is not maintained any more.

The package author provides information for that purpose:

- [How to upgrade from glossary.sty (HTML)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossary2glossaries.html)
- [How to upgrade from glossary.sty (PDF)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossary2glossaries.pdf)

Have a look at [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) for further documentation, such as the manual, a beginner's guide and a link to the author FAQ for the glossaries package.

Perhaps have also a look at

- [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/how-to-keep-up-with-packages-and-know-which-ones-are-obsolete)

Comment: It's not even on TeX Live any more.

Comment: Thanks a lot..  :D After changing everything and fixing some other issues.. it works fine now. :D