# Changing the subfigure caption by removing brackets & font of the subcaption

Tags: fonts, floats, formatting, subfloats

Note that by using `\usepackage[bf]{subfigure}` I'm able to change the label of the subfigure to be boldface. However, the label appears with brackets, e.g., 
"(a)". How could I get a subfigure label that would look like "a)"

Another issue is the font of the text that follows "(a)". What package and options should be put in the preamble to set text to italics?

Comment: the package `subfigure` is outdated, it is superseeded by `subfig`. However, you should use package `caption` by default. It can set nearly everything for the captions.

Comment: But, is it possible to achieve italics with `subfigure`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Understanding that it might be difficult to switch packages, even from a deprecated one, here's an update that addresses your requirements.

- In order get the sub-figure label to be displayed as `a)` instead of `(a)` you have two options:

  - Either redefine the counter displaying mechanism `\thesubfigure`. By default, it is defined as

    ```
    \renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}
    ```

    which adds the parentheses around the (alphabetic) counter `subfigure`. Therefore, using

    ```
    \renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure})}
    ```

    removes the left parenthesis. However, using only this, you need to accept that text label references to sub-figures will also include this adjustment:

    [image]

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[bf]{subfigure}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure})}% (a) -> a)
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \subfigure[First figure\label{subfig1}]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}} \quad
      \subfigure[Second figure\label{subfig2}]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}}
      \caption{Some figures}\label{mainfigure}
    \end{figure}
    See Figure~\ref{subfig1} and~\ref{subfig2}.
    \end{document}
    ```
  - or, change the way the sub-caption is set. That is, not mess with the counter representation, but rather the caption setup. This required a modification to `\thesubfigure` and `\@thesubfigure`:

    [image]

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[bf]{subfigure}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}% (a) -> a
    \renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{\thesubfigure)\hskip\subfiglabelskip}% a -> a)
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \subfigure[First figure\label{subfig1}]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}} \quad
      \subfigure[Second figure\label{subfig2}]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}}
      \caption{Some figures}\label{mainfigure}
    \end{figure}
    See Figure~\ref{subfig1} and~\ref{subfig2}.
    \end{document}
    ```
- Addressing the italic shape of the sub-caption is done using the `IT` package option:

  ```
  \usepackage[bf,IT]{subfigure}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure
  ```

  In general, lower case (old-school) options like `bf`, `it`, and `sf` reference the sub-caption label, while upper case options like `BF`, `IT`, and `SF` reference the sub-caption title/text. See Table 1 (p 6) of the [`subfigure` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.pdf).

Here is a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) using the above suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bf,IT]{subfigure}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}% (a) -> a
\renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{\thesubfigure)\hskip\subfiglabelskip}% a -> a)
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfigure[First figure\label{subfig1}]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}} \quad
  \subfigure[Second figure\label{subfig2}]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}}
  \caption{Some figures}\label{mainfigure}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{subfig1} and~\ref{subfig2}.
\end{document}
```

All of the above discussions pertain to sub-figures. However, since [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) defines an analogous sub-table component, all references to `subfigure` can be replaced with `subtable`.

Comment: Isn't `subfigure` obsolete?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: Indeed. See [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200/5764) The premise of this answer was rather to stick to `subfigure` because of the [OP's request](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61612/changing-the-subfigure-caption-by-removing-brackets-font-of-the-subcaption/61729?noredirect=1#comment130809_61612). Over time there may be many answers on this site using packages that may have become obsolete. It's understandable, and [can be managed](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7174/5764) to some extent.

Answer (score 8):

I would really recommend [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package because it really offers great customization possibilities as sampled below. See also the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) documentation as it is the underlying mechanism behind `subcaption` package from the same author.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe} %<- For some example pictures
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{r-parens}{\textbf{#2)}} %Define our custom label

\captionsetup{font=footnotesize} % The general caption settings
\captionsetup[sub]{              % The subcaption settings
    font=footnotesize,           % Make the font smaller for both label and text
    textfont=sl,                 % Make only the caption text slanted
    labelformat=r-parens}        % Use our custom label format

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Another figure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Figure Caption}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

The Figure \ref{fig:1} has two subfigures Figure~\ref{fig:1a} and Figure~\ref{fig:1b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thank. However, the document I work with has several hundred pages, and `\subfigure[A figure]{}` is used in `figure`. So, I would prefer to just change the preamble, and not to replace the existing code.

Comment: @boy I fear that you have to bite the bullet and change them since you are using an obsolete package. It might come back again and hit you with, say `hyperref` problems. See  [subcaption vs. subfig](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig) for more info.