# How to get rid of \ref's parentheses (e.g., for subfigure)

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I use `\ref` to refer to a subfigure and it shows like this in my text:

```
This thing (Figure 5(b))
```

Double parentheses appear! I want this style:

```
This thing (Figure 5b)
```

How to make it happen?

Comment: What package are you using the produce your subfigures?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which package (or packages) related to the creation of subfigures do you load in your document? There's `subfigure`, `subfig`, `subcaption`, and probably a few others... Knowing exactly which package you use will be important for figuring out the correct method.

Comment: Close-to-duplicate: [Changing the subfigure caption by removing brackets & font of the subcaption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61612/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To suppress just the parentheses around the subfigure's (alpha-style) "number", all you have to do is issue the command

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}} % default: "(\alph{subfigure})"
```

preferably in the document's preamble. However, if the resulting look of cross-references to these objects -- `2c`, `5a`, etc. -- is too sparse-looking for your taste, you may also want to add the following commands to insert a dot (period) between the figure-number and the subfigure-letter:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure.} % default: "\thefigure" (without the ".")
\makeatother
```

to get `2.c`, `5.a`, etc.