# Is it possible to make a reference to a subfigure to appear Figure 2(a) with cleveref?

Tags: subfloats, cleveref

I am new here, and also new to LaTeX, so apologies if I have included too much or too little!

I have been using the `subfig` package, and just today added in `cleveref`.

The subfig package labels my subfigures (a), (b) etc, and I have been using the `\subref` command to make the same appear in the text.

However, using `\cref` (or even `\ref`) in the text to refer to the figure number as well as subfigure letter, there are no parentheses. I would like my output to appear

> figure 2(a)

But instead it appears

> figure 2a

I have been searching a while online, but I can't see how to do this. I see 
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63069/how-to-get-rid-of-refs-parentheses-e-g-for-subfigure) that someone has had the opposite problem and needed to get rid of unwanted parentheses. I can't work out what I have done relative to what he's doing other than that I am using subfig.

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code (more or less)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}      % needed for including graphics e.g. EPS, PS
\usepackage{epstopdf}      % automatic conversion
\usepackage{grffile}       % allow fullstops in graphics file names
\usepackage[format=hang,singlelinecheck=0,font={sf,small},labelfont=bf]{caption, subfig}
                          % allow subfigures
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}      % reference object types automatically

\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\begin{document}

Here is some text and a figure

\begin{figure}

  \begin{minipage}[tbh]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=raggedright}

    \subfloat[text]{\label{fig:1a}\includegraphics{file1.eps}}\qquad
    \subfloat[text]{\label{fig:1b}\includegraphics{file2.eps}}\qquad


    \subfloat[text]{\label{fig:1c}\includegraphics{file3.eps}}\qquad
    \subfloat[text]{\label{fig:1d}\includegraphics{file4.eps}}\qquad

  \end{minipage}

  \caption{\subref{fig:1a} to \subref{fig:1b} are plotted against height, and \subref{fig:1c} to \subref{fig:1d} against pressure}
  \label{fig:1}

\end{figure}

Now I'd like to refer to the figure \ref{fig:1d}. And use cref: \cref{fig:1d}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to set

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple,listofformat=subsimple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

and to use `\subref*`. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[format=hang,singlelinecheck=0,font={sf,small},labelfont=bf]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple,listofformat=subsimple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
\subfloat[text]{\label{fig:1a}\includegraphics{file1.eps}}\qquad
\subfloat[text]{\label{fig:1b}\includegraphics{file2.eps}}\\
\subfloat[text]{\label{fig:1c}\includegraphics{file3.eps}}\qquad
\subfloat[text]{\label{fig:1d}\includegraphics{file4.eps}}
\caption{\protect\subref{fig:1a} to \protect\subref{fig:1b} are plotted against height, and \protect\subref{fig:1c} to \protect\subref{fig:1d} against pressure}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

Now I refer to the figure \subref*{fig:1d}. And use cref: \cref{fig:1d}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

By the way, I made some modifications to your code: to prevent errors, I `\protect`ed the `\subref` commands inside `\caption`. Also I removed the inner `minipage` since its use was not required in this particular example. I didn't load some packages that were not relevant for the issue discussed in this question.

Comment: Thanks very much Gonzalo, not only did you answer my question but you have given me other some useful hints too, and I have even moved my justification commands to the \captionsetup at the top to save me doing it every figure. I am not sure why I was using minipage - I just copied from a previous document, but I can't imagine why I would have needed it in the first place!

Comment: @FionaSmith You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.