# How to add multiple images in one place using captions like Figure x. a, Figure x.b?

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

Is it possible to **caption** the two figures as Figure x.a, Figure x.b?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Why not post an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to explain what you have at the moment, and what you would like to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `subcaption` package does what you are looking for. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{First letter}
[.4\linewidth]{\Huge A}
\subcaptionbox{Second letter}
[.4\linewidth]{\Huge B}
\caption{Two letters}\label{fig:letters}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image: output]

You can include a "graphic" (picture, etc.) by use of the `graphicx` package and then replacing `\Huge A` and `\Huge B` with the command `\includegraphics{<filename>}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subfig` package.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][\emph{Text one}.]
   {\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{file1}} \quad
\subfloat[][\emph{Text 2}.]
   {\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{file2}} \\
\subfloat[][\emph{Text 3}.]
   {\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{file3}} \quad
\subfloat[][\emph{Text4}.]
   {\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{file4}}
\caption{Textr.}
\label{fig:subfig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: An alternative would be `subcaption`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean can you alter the format of how you can change a reference to "Figure 1.x" from "Figure 1x" you might like to check out the answer to a question I asked a while back (note the example shows how you do it both with the standard `ref` and `cleveref`

[Is it possible to make a reference to a subfigure to appear Figure 2(a) with cleveref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75014/)