# Referring to a subfigure

Tags: captions, subfloats, labels, subcaption

I am writing up my thesis and I have some subfigures. When I typeset the code, the subfigures are labelled (a) and (b), however when I refer to the subfigures in the text, I get Figure 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 instead of 4.1(a) and 4.1(b). How do I change the code to get 4.1(a) instead of 4.1.1 in the text? The code I am using for the figures is shown below:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]

  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,valign=t]{figures/chapter4/1.pdf}
    \phantomcaption
    \label{fig:1}
    \end{center}
  \end{subfigure}


  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
   \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, valign=t]{figures/chapter4/2.pdf}
   \phantomcaption
    \label{fig:2}
      \end{center}
  \end{subfigure}


\caption{Graphs showing..}  
\label{fig:Demand}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code compilable?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75014/is-it-possible-to-make-a-reference-to-a-subfigure-to-appear-figure-2a-with-cle

Comment: Which document class do you employ? How and/or where is the option `valign=t` defined?

Comment: You wrote, "When I typeset the code, the subfigures are labelled (a) and (b)". Actually, since the code contains `\phantomcaption` directives, I don't see how it could generating captions labeled `(a)` and `(b)`. Please clarify what's going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding parentheses around subfig references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16291/adding-parentheses-around-subfig-references)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `\phantomcaption` statements, not "real" `\caption` statements, inside the `subfigure` environments, all you should need to do is issue the directive

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

in the preamble. (If you did use `\caption` statements, you'd also have to provide the directive `\captionsetup[subcaption]{labelformat=simple}`.)

A separate comment: You also ought to simplify and streamline the code in the `figure` environment, e.g., by having a single `\centering` statement and setting up the `subfigure` environments to occupy widths equal to `0.8\textwidth`. The following shows how this might be done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} % is this right?
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\captionsetup[subcaption]{labelformat=simple} % not needed here
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4} % just for this example

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth%,valign=t
      ]{figures/chapter4/1.pdf}
    \phantomcaption
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth%, valign=t
      ]{figures/chapter4/2.pdf}
    \phantomcaption
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}

\caption{Graphs showing \dots}  
\label{fig:Demand}
\end{figure}

Cross-references to subfigures \ref{fig:1} and \ref{fig:2}.
\end{document}
```