# Editing the reference style for subfigures using cleveref and memoir

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, subfloats, cleveref

I'm using the `cleveref` package to reference floats (in this case subfigures) in the `memoir` class. Currently the output looks like this (sorry for the danish, I don't think it matters):
[image: subfigures in memoir using cleveref]

Using the following input (not all packages included, ofc):

```
\documentclass[oneside,article,12pt,danish]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\captiontitlefont{\slshape}
\subcaptionfont{\slshape}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \subbottom[Subfigure 1 caption]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}\label{sub1}}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \subbottom[Subfigure 2 caption]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}\label{sub2}}
\caption{Figure text.}
\label{fig:secondfig}
\end{figure}

\cref{sub1,sub2}

\end{document}
```

I like the way the figure/subfigures are set up, but I would like the reference to say `5a` or `5.a` instead of `5(a)` without changing the figure/subfigure captions. Is there a general way to do this in the entire document, so that it can be easilly be changed to a somewhat random notation?

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63069/how-to-get-rid-of-refs-parentheses-e-g-for-subfigure Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the exact answer. I might be missing something obvious? The problem is that when I change the reference to e.g. "5a" the subfigure caption also changes to "a" (I still want the parentheses in the caption). I figured there might be a memoir specific way of doing this?

Comment: I don't have too much time to think this through right now (might try tonight) but I had the opposite problem - My reference was saying 5a and I wanted it to say 5(a). Maybe compare what I had against yours and you might be able to work it out? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75014/is-it-possible-to-make-a-reference-to-a-subfigure-to-appear-figure-2a-with-cle?rq=1

Comment: I've read it but it didn't help me. I tried using the caption package and the `\captionsetup[subfigure]{...}` but no luck. I wasn't able to find any options in the documentation, and the ones used didn't work. FYI: It's not urgent.

Comment: Well if I want distracting from my thesis when I get home tonight I will have a tinker. I'm not an expert on this sort of thing though - I just noticed nobody had replied to you and it was the sort of thing I'd fought with before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution avoids the need to load `caption` and thereby retains the facilities of `memoir`. At least, it seems so although my testing has been somewhat minimal. Uncomment/comment the appropriate line to achieve formatting with or without the dot, as the mood takes you.

```
\documentclass[oneside,article,12pt,danish]{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\captiontitlefont{\slshape}
\subcaptionfont{\slshape}

% \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}% plain version
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{.\alph{subfigure}}% dotted version
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})%
    \if@tightsubcap\hskip\subfloatlabelskip\else\space\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \subbottom[Subfigure 1 caption]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}\label{sub1}}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \subbottom[Subfigure 2 caption]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}\label{sub2}}
\caption{Figure text.}
\label{fig:secondfig}
\end{figure}

\cref{sub1,sub2}

\end{document}
```

[image: sub figures with variant referencing format in <code>memoir</code>]

Were you to load `xcolor` then you could (perversely) have just the references to the sub-figure bits typeset in huge, blue lowercase without affecting the captions or other references:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Huge\color{blue}.\alph{subfigure}}% dotted version
```

[image: bizarre formatting]

Obviously, this would be a terrible choice but it demonstrates that the format can be easily 'changed to a somewhat random notation' while retaining the format of sub-captions and the interface of `memoir`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's a partial suggestion using `subfig` and `caption`. I've not used the memoir class before. If I use article, figures are labelled "1.a", when I switch to memoir I get "0.1.a". Some of your code doesn't compile for me. I've commented it out. I've changed the figure to look more like my own code (i.e. `subfloat` not `subbottom`)  because I haven't used the latter before. I've incorporated the answer to the question I linked to before.

So, with the caveats above about the non-compiling code, my example here does what you want in terms of figure labelling (I think).

There's probably a better solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}



%%%%These do not work for me - is there a missing package?
%\newsubfloat{figure}
%\captiontitlefont{\slshape}
%\subcaptionfont{\slshape}
%%%%

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage[font=sl,labelfont=up]{caption}
\usepackage[font=sl,labelfont=up]{subfig}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}} % default: "(\alph{subfigure})"
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure.} % default: "\thefigure" (without the ".")
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Subfigure 1 caption]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}\label{sub1}}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \subfloat[Subfigure 2 caption]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}\label{sub2}}
\caption{Figure text.}
\label{fig:secondfig}
\end{figure}

\cref{sub1,sub2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, now there's another "problem" (it's small stuff, I know). The "Figure 0.1" (the numbering is easily changed, don't worry about that) and "(a)" is italic--or slanted, as I prefer. I don't know how to change this without changing the rest of the caption text. I've read/heard that memoir is made to be editable so I think there _must_ be some way of doing this easily without using e.g. the subfigure package (keyword: think). That's why I use `subbottom`. When I uncomment the stuff you've commented I get errors too. That is, unless I use `subbottom` instead of `subfloat`. Weird.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I really appreciate the feedback! (I had no space left in the comment above for this.) And by the way, the things you commented in my document is used for making the sub-/captions slanted (globally). I think it's part of the (in memoir preloaded) `ccaption` package. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, you can use `\usepackage[font=sl,labelfont=up]{caption}` will edit the answer. I agree I am sure that's what the lines I commented out look like they are doing - I don't know why it didn't work for me but I haven't used memoir before. I don't know why nobody else is answering your question - but I think it would help to have someone who has used memoir!!

Comment: By the way, I can see why you don't want to use `caption` because it is clearly overwriting some memoir-specific stuff - that said, it seems to work! Generates the message: `Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the memoir class. To prepare we will now reset all captioni
ng macros and configurations to kernel defaults, and then let the caption package take over. Please remember to use the 
caption package interfaces in order to configure your captions.'