# change numbering in subfigure

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I use subfigure package, the numbering in the side-by-side figures is automatically (a), (b), (c)... I would like to change the numbering in one of the figures to (i), (ii), (iii)...This might be rather easy for the tex experts. If so, please drop me an advice, thanks! Yanting.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61612/156344

Comment: the`subfigure` package is obsolete. it is replaced with `subfig` (`\subfloat[...]{\includegraphics{<name>}}`). it would be even better to follow the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. However, this command has changed all the numberings to roman throughout the manuscript, what I need is to only change the numbering in one figure to roman, and the numberings in other figures remain alphabetical. Is that possible without switching the package? (still use subfigure package) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\roman{subfigure})}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfigure[A subfigure\label{a}]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}} \quad
  \subfigure[Another subfigure\label{b}]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{Some figures}\label{mainfigure}
\end{figure}
See Figures \ref{a} and \ref{b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, `subfigure` is obsolete. Use `subcaption` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\roman{subfigure})}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A subfigure}
    \label{a}
  \end{subfigure}\quad%
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Another subfigure}
    \label{b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Some figures}\label{mainfigure}
\end{figure}
See Figures \ref{a} and \ref{b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (i) read my comment: don't encourage OP to use obsolete pacages (ii) using this package you already found answer for op question, so yours is duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

- the `subfigure package is obsolete. it is replaced with`subfig`which define`subfloat` environment:

  ```
  \subfloat[...]{\includegraphics{<imge file name>}}).
  ```
- you can change numbering of sub figures with

  ```
  \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure}}
  ```

it would be even better to follow the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{sub caption a}
  \label{fig:figure-1.a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfil
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{sub caption b}
  \label{fig:figure-1.b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfil
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{sub caption c}
  \label{fig:figure-1.c}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{My figures}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
See Figures \ref{fig:figure-1.a}, \ref{fig:figure-1.b} and \ref{fig:figure-1.c} \dots
```

[image]