# How to vertically align 3 images with subfigure?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, subfloats

This code:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{center}
        \begin{subfigure}[a]{0.3\textwidth}
                \label{im:device_front}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/bsn_side}
        \caption{a) Frontal view of the sensor system}
    \end{subfigure}
                \quad    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \label{im:device_schuin}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/bsn_front}
        \caption{b) Perspective view of the sensor system}
    \end{subfigure} 
            \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \label{im:device_side}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/bsn_schuin}
        \caption{c) Side view of the sensor system}
    \end{subfigure} 
\caption{Overview of the system as worn by the subjects}
\label{default}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

produces result:

[image]

But I want them to be vertically aligned. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `[b]` for the first `subfigure`, similar to the other two. You should also consider using [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) since [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is deprecated.

Comment: aah, thank you, I thought the [a],[b] and [c] was for enumeration purposes.

Comment: @Werner OP's probably using `subcaption` package.

Comment: Who's this guy, may I ask? :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul why would that be relevant? happy to share in PM though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The interface provided by the [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package, specifies the first (optional) argument to indicate the vertical alignment. Using `[b]` should align be `b`ottom of the sub figures. Analogously, `[t]` should align the `t`ops.

Instead of numbering the captions manually

```
\caption{a) ...}
```

you could use the accompanying `\subfigure` command:

```
\subfigure{...}
```

and change the format of the numbering to your liking.

Comment: `subcaption` seems to be incompatible with `subfig`. Is there a solution. But I have many `subfloat`s. Is there a solution with `subfig` / one that does not require to change all subfloats (without setting height explicitly)?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out this easy solution. I've seen others where they use minipages inside minipages to align images and captions separately and was already losing hope.

Comment: @Big_Chair: The [`subfigure` package](//ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is considered [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764). It's best to use the [`subcaption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption); it's distributed with the [`caption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/caption), something that is pretty standard for setting `\caption` properties and layouts.

Answer (score 48):

I simply couldn't pass this one by, if only just to produce a solution that makes note of the obvious similarities between the sample provided and the classic `Tron Guy`.

The actual solution uses `subfig` package, but who cares.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelsep=quad,indention=10pt]{subfig}
\captionsetup*[subfigure]{position=bottom}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
           \subfloat[Frontal view]{%
              \includegraphics[height=5cm]{tron_side.jpg}%
              \label{fig:left}%
           } 
           \subfloat[Perspective view]{%
              \includegraphics[height=5cm]{tron_front.jpg}%
              \label{fig:middle}%
           }
           \subfloat[Side view]{%
              \includegraphics[height=5cm]{tron_right2.jpg}%
              \label{fig:right}%
           }
           \caption{Overview of the sensor system as worn by the subjects.}
           \label{fig:default}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: But in your example you're using 3 pictures of the same size.  I thought the point of the question was to align pictures of different sizes.

Comment: also the captions are mixed up

Comment: @Andreina They are not of the same size. They are of different sizes. They were scaled proportionately to have the same height so they could be aligned, and that is my solution.

Answer (score 10):

I found this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=67mm]{PipeScannerUnderGround}}
\subfigure{\raisebox{10mm}{\includegraphics[width=47mm]{CylScanGeometryPipe}}}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

[here](http://tooloftrade.blogspot.no/2012/05/adjusting-vertical-alignment-of.html)

Worked perfectly :)

Use `\usepackage{subfigure}` in the preamble

Answer (score 1):

From webpage https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gull}
        \caption{A gull}
        \label{fig:gull}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}
        \caption{A tiger}
        \label{fig:tiger}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
    %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mouse}
        \caption{A mouse}
        \label{fig:mouse}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures of animals}\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Without some more content, this doesn't really add much more value than is already included in the OP. What is the vertical alignment if `gull`, `tiger` and `mouse` have different heights?