# Importing plots from MATLAB to LaTeX

Tags: graphics, floats, matlab

This is my first time trying to import plots created by MATLAB into LaTeX and it's not turning out very nicely. I have saved my MATLAB plot as a .png file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpy1qlj634scmaa/graph2.png) and an .eps file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/scp2hsl011k3gvy/graph2.eps). Using the .eps file, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{graph2.eps}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

which turns out to look like: (half the image is missing)

[image]

So then I changed the scale to 0.4:

```
 \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{graph2.eps}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

However now the image is way too small to be eligible (and it doesn't feel like it's centered properly). Does anyone have a good solution for this? How can I get the image to look "good" when imported into LaTeX? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have saved the three plots separately:

The first graph is called g1 and can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7tublmkuqad6tw/g1.eps)

g2 can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wxv5p4uw15x9m7/g2.eps)

and g3 can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/31o2z1z2ip9js2q/g3.eps)

How can I combine them into one figure using the tabular environment? Could someone provide a template code?

Comment: Just a tip: You need to crop the image to get rid of white space. For this task you could use ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick/GIMP (png file) or eps->pdf conversion supported by the pdfcrop tool (pdf file) and eventually back to eps file.

Comment: Personally, I use [`matlab2tikz`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) and it works perfectly.

Comment: For what it's worth, it might also be a good idea to export these three graphs separately (and maybe the legend as well, or attach it to every graph), then you are slightly more flexible in positioning the images.

Comment: I recommend moewe's suggestion and inclusion of the separate images in a tabular environment to align them?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post where I saved each graph separately. Could you please provide a template code utilizing the tabular environment to align them?

Comment: Tip: use `width=` option instead of `scale` when importing graphics. This scales graphics to desired sizes. Eg, `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph2.eps}`.

Comment: @moewe The pics are gone. Do you know a good question that might suit as a duplicate? Or do you wanna write an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Take your pick: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148438/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5769/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37581/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65386/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10245/35864. Maybe there is something better and more specific out there, but those are the questions a short search turned up.