# Adding "\usepackage{subfig}" (no other changes in file) throws error

Tags: subfloats, incompatibility

I want to use the `subfig` package to have a neat row of figures with captions for each one of them. However, as soon as I add the line `\usepackage{subfig}`, pdfLaTeX fails with the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \sf@counterlist 

l.54 \begin{document}
```

I have commented this line (and the corresponding lines where I am actually using the subfig package) and everything works fine. The preamble is

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-10pt}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{epsfig,url,hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
\newcommand{\eat}[1]{}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\tightcaption}[1]{\vspace{-0.2cm}\caption{#1}\vspace{-0.2cm}}

\begin{document}
```

And here's the part where I am using the subfloats:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\subfloat[2006]{\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth, height=.24\textwidth, frame]{figures/2006-cloud-crop.pdf}} &
\subfloat[2007]{\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth, height=.24\textwidth, frame]{figures/2007-cloud-crop.pdf}} &
\subfloat[2008]{\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth, height=.24\textwidth, frame]{figures/2008-cloud-crop.pdf}} &
\subfloat[2009]{\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth, height=.24\textwidth, frame]{figures/2009-cloud-crop.pdf}} \\
\subfloat[2010]{\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth, height=.24\textwidth, frame]{figures/2010-cloud-crop.pdf}} &
\subfloat[2011]{\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth, height=.24\textwidth, frame]{figures/2011-cloud-crop.pdf}} &
\subfloat[2012]{\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth, height=.24\textwidth, frame]{figures/2012-cloud-crop.pdf}} &
\subfloat[2013]{\includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth, height=.24\textwidth, frame]{figures/2013-cloud-crop.pdf}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Is this error thrown due to some package incompatibility? I am a little taken aback by the error being thrown right after the preamble.

Comment: You have to choose between `subfigure` or `subfig`, but not both. Try *without* the former.

Comment: That worked! I was using subfigure before, but upon learning that it's obsolete, I switched to subfig. Is there a central list/repository for LaTeX where the package incompatibilities are mentioned? Also ... please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: There is [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is considered obsolete by the package author:

> The pack­age is now con­sid­ered ob­so­lete: it was su­per­seded by [`sub­fig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig), but users may find the more re­cent [`sub­cap­tion`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) pack­age more sat­is­fac­tory.

Remove it from your preamble and use `subfig` *only*.

Comment: Also for me has worked the solution above. The problem is that the packages *subfigure* and *subfloat* are in conflict with each other. So we need to enable the *subfig* package and disable the *subfigure* one.