# Error on including subfig package

Tags: subfloats

Adding `\usepackage{subfig}` in my code give the following error

`! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \sf@counterlistl.40 \begin{document}`

I tried commenting all other packages except `subfig`, however the error persists. 
The preamble of my file looks as follows

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{pdfsync}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{inputenc}
%\usepackage{paralist}
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{standalone}
%\usepackage{vector} 
\usepackage{epigraph}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{Thesis}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}
```

[this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170587/adding-usepackagesubfig-no-other-changes-in-file-throws-error) question is similar, however I am not using the `caption` package

The following minimal code reproduces the error on my machine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{image_path}}&
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{image_path}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please provide the simplest code, which we can compile and which exibits your problem. With following simple MWE I cannot reproduce your problem: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{subfig}\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
\end{figure}\end{document}`

Comment: Thesis class, there is more than one so where we can find this one

Comment: It seems that problems lie in documentclass `thesis`. In Other documentclass-es (article, book) your MWE works. Unfortunately, I don't know it.

Comment: The problem was with the Thesis cls file. The file included the subfigure package which was causing problems. Thanks for you help