# Commands for beamer environment

Tags: beamer

Could you help in adjusting this list of commands? It gives me several errors, but I don't understand why.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\begin{beamercolorbox}{author in head/foot}
\usebeamerfont{authorinhead/foot}
% \vskip3pt \hskip3pt \insertshortauthor
\vskip2pt \hskip5pt \insertsection \hfill
(\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber) \hskip3pt
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\Def}{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}} %Black%
\newcommand{\Blue}{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}
\newcommand{\beginbackup}{
   \newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}
   \setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
   \addtocounter{framenumbervorappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
   \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}} 
}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1$}}


\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}{name=}
\captionsetup[figure]{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
blah blah
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And we are supposed to guess which errors show up... Let me look into my crystal ball... ah yes... option clashes because `xcolor` and `graphicx` are included multiple times with contradicting options

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to Latex. Could you tell which lines I should remove? I tried to remove usepackage{xcolor} and usepackage{graphicx}, but then I get problems with usepackage{subfig}. Thanks

Comment: Keep `\usepackage{graphicx}` but without the `[demo]` option. It seems, that that option conflicts with `subfig` package (I never used them both in conjunction, so it is just a guess)

Comment: You can't use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` in beamer. Just delete this line. `xcolor` is used doubled. If you don't know, what the options are fore, just delete the longer version. You don't need `color`, if you already load `xcolor`. I would prefer to use `subcaption` over `subfig`, but in `beamer` this does not matter that much.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `[demo]` conflicts with `beamer`. Don't ask me why. @user52584 Delete all lines, you do not actually need. Then comment out half of the code in your preamble and look, if the errors disappear. That's how we do minimal examples here. I commented everything out, until I noticed, that just `[demo]{graphicx}` without anything else results in an error.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Ok, good to know, I never used `beamer` with `demo` mode of``graphicx`.

Comment: @user52584 Great. Maybe you subscribe to this page with a username which is nicer then userxyz and accept the answer as such. This is, how we say thank you here. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi `demo` (or any other option passed to `graphicx` in `\usepackage`, which by the way is not required since the package is already loaded) for `graphicx` in `beamer` produces a clash because internally `beamer` already loads `graphicx` *without* options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do not load packages twice
- Do not use `[demo]` from `graphicx` in `beamer`, or if you want to use it, pass the option as class option to prevent a clash (internally beamer loads `graphicx` without options):

  ```
  \documentclass[demo]{beamer}
  ```
- Do not pass `[usenames]` or `[dvipsnames]` to `xcolor` directly in `beamer`; pass the option as class option to prevent a clash (internally `beamer` loads `xcolor` without options):

  ```
  \documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
  ```
- `color` is already loaded by `xcolor`, so leave the former away.
- Have a look in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910) to see, which packages have become obsolete

Comment: I edited the answer. I don't like to edit other people's answers, so that's why I left the comments.