# Why pspicture shows error?

Tags: pstricks

Let us consider the following example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.02)(2.68,0.02)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.0,0.0)(2.66,0.0)
\end{pspicture}
 }
\end{document}
```

Whenever I compile this code with kile in Ubuntu14.04 shows four errors :

Undefine control sequence }

Undefine control sequence }

Undefine control sequence }

Undefine control sequence }

But I don't know why such errors are occurring. Please help.

Comment: No problem here. You should probably [update your distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764) and make sure you compile with LaTeX/XeLaTeX, not pdfLaTeX. Also, drop the use of the [deprecated `epsfig`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764) and use [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) instead.

Comment: What control sequence is shown as undefined? The full log will give proper detail.

Comment: @Werner I have compiled with pdflatex

Comment: you did not show the error message the undefined command is `\c@lor@to@ps` by default pstricks only works with latex not pslatex, use latex and the error will go. Don't use `epsfig` !!

Comment: To compile with `pdflatex`, load the `auto-pstpdf` package (or add the `pdf` option to pstricks options) and compile with the `--enable-write18` switch fore MiKTeX, or `-shell-escape` for TeX Live or MacTeX.

Comment: Run your document with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`

Comment: Or rename your `pdflatex` to any unused filename and rename your `xelatex` to `pdflatex`.