# What does runningheads do in the documentclass?

Tags: document-classes, class-options

Although I'm a TeX/LaTeX neophyte, I've taken on a rather ambitious project of updating [Differential Calculus with SAGE](http://wdjoyner.com/teach/calc1-sage/). As I go along I'm using the existing `tex` document to teach myself what each piece of code does. And right at the start, I'm stumped.

Line 5 of the master file reads

```
\documentclass[10pt,runningheads]{book}
```

but I can't find any place where this option is documented. There are only blank lines and comments above this, and googling for "latex documentclass runningheads" hasn't resulted in any useful information.

As a side question, I suppose that I'm also wondering if there's any definitive place to go for documentation on all of the LaTeX macros and their options.

Comment: `book` doesn't take `runningheads` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A specification of the form

```
\documentclass[<optA>,<optB>,...,<optN>]{<class>}
```

applies any of the options `<optA>`,...,`<optN>` to `<class>`. Some might not apply to `<class>` and is stored in a macro `\@unusedoptionlist`. Some of these options may apply when loading a package

```
\usepackage[<opts>]{<package>}
```

as well. Any remaining `\@unusedoptionlist` entries will cause a warning. [`source2e`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) briefly mentions this (p 62):

> `\@unusedoptionlist`
>
> List of options of the main class that haven’t been declared or loaded as class
>   option files.

Since there is no reference to `runningheads` in [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) (the original source), it must apply to another package (perhaps one dealing with headers/footers).

Comment: One may know for certain where `runningheads` applies to by issuing `\makeatletter \show\@unusedoptionlist \makeatother` throughout the document preamble, and see where it could get gobbled up... without greater detail of the preamble it's not easy to know.

Comment: I suspect this is just a leftover from a copy-paste from a document using the Springer `llncs` document class which has `runningheads` as class option to include the title and some other info in the header.

Comment: I don't want to paste the entire preamble here, but you can find it at https://github.com/chivalry/differential-calculus-and-sage/blob/master/wdjoyner-files/latex/granville-calculus.tex. There is a later delcaration of `\usepackage{fancyheadings}`, so perhaps it's to do with that. I haven't yet researched the packages that are included.

Comment: @Chuck `fancyheadings` is an obsolete package superseded by `fancyhdr`. I found this old documentation for the former http://www.fi.infn.it/pub/tex/doc/orig/fancyheadings.pdf and no mention of `runningheads`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, well, that's part of my cleanup duties. :) This project was last updated in '08 or so, so that's probably why it's using obsolete packages.

Comment: @Chuck: Related: [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764)

Comment: '08 well perhaps. fancyheadings was obsoleted by fancyhdr (by the same author) in 1994 name change motivated by requirements of use with MSDOS and ISO format CDs:-)