# Problem having figures side by side

Tags: floats, subfloats

I wish to add to subfigures side by side and have the following code

```
 \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{figures/figure1}%
\caption{bla1}
\label{fig:CL1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{figures/figure2}%
\caption{bla2}
\label{fig:CL2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{bla bla bla}%
\label{fig:CL}
\end{figure}
```

I've also tried removing the "%" sign after subfigure 1, but makes no difference. I'm using the package "subfigure", so I'm not sure what I am missing to get it to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is [obsolete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764). Use [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The package `subfigure` is obsolete. You should use `subcaption` or `subfig` packages for this facility. Here is your case with `subcaption`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{bla1}
\label{fig:CL1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{bla2}
\label{fig:CL2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{bla bla bla}
\label{fig:CL}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem like subcaption helps. I've tried adding the packages, but end up getting the errors. It doesn't seem like it knows when the subfigures end.

Comment: @JonasN89 Please update your tex distribution

Comment: I'm using texnicCenter, I don't know if that has anything to do with it? My tex distribution, what is that?