# Continued numbering in subfigure of selected figures

Tags: xetex, subfloats, subcaption

I am very confused about for the continued  numbering in subfigure of selected figures.

I want format a continued numbering in subfigures of selected figures, but not for all the figures. At the same time, the numbering in figures remains. The example code is as following,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}  
\usepackage[]{graphicx}  
\usepackage{subfigure}  

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb] %numbering in  arabic 
\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}  
   \centering  
    \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:1}   
        \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
    }
    \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:2} 
        \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
    } 
   \caption{1111111111111。}\label{fig:111} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
   \centering
    \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:a} 
        \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
    }
    \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:b} 
        \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
    }   
   \caption{2222222222。}\label{fig:222} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]  %numbering in continued arabic
\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
   \centering
    \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:3} 
        \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
    }   
    \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:4} 
        \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image} 
    }   
   \caption{3333333。}\label{fig:3333} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is a picture for the problem. 
[image]

Comment: The `subfigure` couter is reset with every new `figure`. If you want Figure 3 subfigures to be 3 and 4, add `\setcounter{subfigure}{2}` just before your first `\subfigure`.

Comment: By the way, [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is obsolete. Rather use [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). See [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments! I have a lot of graphics in the document, so the manually adding `\setcounter{subfigure}{2}` is not very convenient.

Comment: As companion to the (obsolete) `subfigure` package an (obsolete) package called `captcont` is offered for continued captions.

Comment: I can format all of the subfigures of figures with continued numbers. However, I can't  continued number the subfigures of selected figures.

Comment: I'm not aware of an existing solution to this. So it seems you need to write your own macros which are able to save and restore the `subfigure` counter value.