# `'not found .`\end{frame}`

Tags: beamer, xetex, errors, compiling

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}
\usepackage{xecolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%%%%%%%%%% table
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                  Color of ‌Bullet
\newcommand*\MyPitem{%
    \item[\color{fg=brown!35!red}\scalebox{1.1}{\textbullet}]}
\newcommand*\MyCitem{%
    \item[\color{pink}\scalebox{1.1}{\textbullet}]}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5            Color of b‌lock
\newenvironment{variableblock}[3]{%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{#2}
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{#3}
    \begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip1.5ex}{}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[super,numbers,sort & compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=green!55!blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=green!70!blue}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.143333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.593333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.263333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hspace{3cm}
 \vspace{2.3cm}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55
\setbeamertemplate{headline} {
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %
 \usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=2.5cm]{}}
    %$ $  $ $
    \logo{%
        \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logo}%
    }

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide].
\end{frame}
\logo{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{}% 
    }
    \logo{%
        \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logo}%
    }
```

When I compile, it displays the error:

though it generates the PDF file correctly. I'd like to get it working correctly since it is a little annoying to get that error every time I compile.
I removed `\usepackage{subfig}` to solve one error about Undefined control sequence `\begin{ducument}`
and this command have this error::
`'not found .`\end{frame}`

Comment: Do not use `\includegraphics{}` as this looks for a file with an empty file name (unless you make sure you have an image without a name)

Comment: aha...you mean that I should edit name for \includegraphics{}?

Comment: Why do you have `\logo{\includegraphics[...]{...}}` in four places? Why isn't one enough?

Comment: At least you should write a file name inside the `{}`.

Comment: do you _really_ need all those packages? You seem to be using xetex so you definitely should not be using `inputenc` or `fontenc` or `epstopdf`

Comment: related discussion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307485/undefined-control-sequence-endframe-in-beamer-document?lq=1

Comment: @Gremler I use defference photo by this command

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I try to fix it

Comment: Please delete this question (otherwise it will most likely be closed) as it seems to be an exact duplicate of your previous one

Comment: sorry for post duplicate questions :( I come here firt time

Comment: You don't have `\end{document}`. You are loading many packages twice or more with incompatible options. You are loading packages loaded by Beamer. You are loading packages which you cannot possibly need or make no sense with Beamer. You are using `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` around code which contains no `@`. It is not, to be honest, surprising if it doesn't compile without error. But the specific error appears to be that you have used the environment `ducument`, which is not defined, rather than `document`, which would be. But your MWE will not reproduce this error.

Comment: Or maybe that was the first error - not clear as you've not provided complete error messages. But, if so, that's nothing to do with `subfig`.

Comment: @all In the CW answer below I tried to summarise the comments. Feel free to edit if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

I think the immediate cause of this error message were the empty brackets in `\includegraphics{}`, as this will look for an image with an empty file name which will most likely not be found.

But to avoid further errors, much of the superfluous code should be removed.

- `beamer` itself provides many packages, so there is no need use `graphicx`, `hyperref`, `color` or `xcolor`. On the contrary, if you call them yourself a second time, you risk to get in trouble with contradictory package options.
- Do not load packages multiple times. For example `caption` is at least loaded three times.
- Try not to use obsolete packages, for a (incomplete) list see [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3910/how-to-keep-up-with-packages-and-know-which-ones-are-obsolete)
- As @DavidCarlisle wrote in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307489/not-found-endframe#comment746331_307489) `inputenc`, `fontenc` and `epstopdf` should not be used with `xetex`.

---

The attempt to clean up a bit:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\newcommand*\MyPitem{%
    \item[\color{fg=brown!35!red}\scalebox{1.1}{\textbullet}]}
\newcommand*\MyCitem{%
    \item[\color{pink}\scalebox{1.1}{\textbullet}]}

\newenvironment{variableblock}[3]{%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{#2}
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{#3}
    \begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip1.5ex}{}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=green!55!blue}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=green!70!blue}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.143333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.593333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.263333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \hspace{3cm}
        \vspace{2.3cm}
      \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2ex]{section in head/foot}%
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }

    \setbeamertemplate{background}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=2.5cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}%
  }

  \logo{%
       \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}%
    }

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide]
    \end{frame}

  \logo{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}%
  }

    \begin{frame}
        another logo
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much..you right.  ..Since I use a lot of packages I confuse  by them