# How to break a line in currvita's \item

Tags: lists, line-breaking, currvita

I'm writing my CV using

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{currvita}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\begin{document}   


\begin{cvlist}

\item[Line 1 \newline Line 2] Second column

\end{cvlist}

\end{document}
```

I would like Line 1 to be on a line and Line 2 to be on another line, but `\newline` doesn't work, I do not get an error, simply the line doesn't break. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so that it can be compiled to reproduce the problem and explain what `doesn't work` means. Does it strike and suggest ACAS talks? Does it give an error? What is the error? However, if you want to break lines here, a `tabular` might be more suitable than a list.

Comment: I edited the question. @cfr

Comment: Off-topic: don't load `epsfig` at all. Load `hyperref` last unless a specific package requires otherwise.

Comment: ok.....but why?

Comment: Because: [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764) and [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just set the item inside a small `tabular` using [`makecell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currvita,makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{cvlist}{Heading}
  \item[{\makecell[lt]{First line \\ Second line}}] Second column

  \item[{\makecell[t]{First line \\ Second line}}] Second column
\end{cvlist}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of extra braces `{`...`}` around `\makecell` to avoid confusion about the optional argument for `\item` and `\makecell`.

Comment: that worked, thank you. What do [lt] and [t] do?

Comment: @user113589: The optional argument for `\makecell` sets the alignment. I've used `l`eft and `t`op. Read more about the available options in the [`makecell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf).

Comment: To me solution with makecell did not workout: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370085/7128