# Line-breaking of item title in cvlist of currvita

Tags: lists, line-breaking, currvita

How to break line in list item?

I have following CV, where some item titles are too long and would like to break them. Unfortunately simple `\\` does not do the job.

Example of CV where item title does not fit and would be nice to break:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TextAligned,NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{cv}{Lorem ipsum Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{cvlist}{Lorem ipsum}
\item[Long Long Lorem ipsum] \lipsum[1]
\item[{\makecell[t]{Long Long\\ Lorem ipsum}}] \lipsum[1]
\end{cvlist}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

(as visible on example , solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328320/7128 did not work out)

Answer (score 2):

Hulk-`\smash` it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[TextAligned,NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{cv}{Lorem ipsum Curriculum Vitae}
  \begin{cvlist}{Lorem ipsum}
    \item[Long Long Lorem ipsum] \lipsum[1]
    \item[\smash{\makecell[t]{Long Long\\ Lorem ipsum}}] \lipsum[1]
  \end{cvlist}
\end{cv}

\end{document}
```