# How to move the caption of a subfigure right?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats

My demo code is as follows. Now the caption of each subfigure is displayed centered.
How can I move each caption (including the counter) by 0.5cm right?

[PS: I want the caption "(a) Data" is aligned centrally to the center of "Threshold".]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[caption for a]{
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
}
\subfigure[capture for b]{
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
}
\subfigure[caption for c]{
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why 5mm and why to the *right*? Do you want the sub-figure caption *right*-aligned with the size of the image, perhaps?

Comment: Note that [`subfigure` is considered obsolete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200/5764).

Comment: Sorry, my english is poor. I have uploaded a sample figure. I want to align the caption "(a) Data" centrally to the center of "Threshold".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue lies with the vertical axis labels that are included in your image. Since they protrude out to the left, it seems like the sub-caption should shift to the right.

One way to fix this - which is independent of the sub-figure package you may be using, is to insert some space to the right of the images, thereby simulating some axis labels on the right. Alternatively, you can shift the caption to the *left* by inserting some space at the *right* of the sub-caption.

Here are some examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{First}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
  }\qquad
  \subcaptionbox{Second}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}%
  }

  \bigskip

  \subcaptionbox{First}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}\hspace*{2em}%
  }\qquad
  \subcaptionbox{Second}{%
    \hspace*{2em}\includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}%
  }

  \bigskip

  \subcaptionbox{First\hspace*{2em}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
  }\qquad
  \subcaptionbox{\makebox[0pt][l]{Second}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}%
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, (a) and (b) are the controls, while (c) and (d) have spaces set to the right and left of the images, respectively. This enlarges the "images", thereby shifting the caption. (e) shifts the caption to the left as a result of adding space to the right. (f) shifts the caption to the right by setting the caption in a `[l]`eft-aligned box of lesser (`0pt`) width.

Comment: It works well. Thanks a lot for your kind help. But I still have a question. If I have fixed the size and interval of all figures, I wonder if it is possible to tackle this problem by only using the command "\subfigure"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. I have modified the template and replaced subfigure with subfig. Now it works well.

Comment: Isn't there a solution where the label can be shifted? My images are so big that I can't insert space...

Comment: @trinity420: Do you have whitespace around your images? If so, you can clip/trim those.

Comment: @Werner No, I have not. However, I switched to subfig package which solves this problem in a one-liner, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler and better solution than the accepted, without adding space to images (e.g. when your images are too big). Just add:

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{oneside,margin={0.5cm,0cm}}
```

before `\begin{subfigure}`. Adjust to your desired margin. To change it for another subfigure, just re-use it and change amount of shifting.