# Undefined control sequence \EnableCrossrefs

Tags: undefined

I'm having some trouble with this. I'm quite new to LaTeX, and I'm just trying to recreate a word document in LaTeX. Here's the full error:

```
E: c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colordoc/colordoc.sty:155 Undefined control sequence \EnableCrossrefs
```

And here's my preamble if that helps at all:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,multicol,amsthm,multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,dashrule,colordoc,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} %% to put boxes 
\usepackage{float}
\cfoot{\thepage}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `\EnableCrossrefs` is not a standard command (or one I recognise at all) where are you using it? Unrelated but don't use `epsfig` package unless emulating a document from 1980's

Comment: I don't think I'm using it at all yet. I'm trying to take my professor's code from his latex file and copy it into mine. The only thing I've copied so far are the `\usepackage` parts from his file.

Comment: Remove colordoc, besides epsfig

Comment: @TheDetective: See [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764)

Answer (score 2):

If you must use the `colordoc` package -- and you almost certainly need not -- you should also load the `doc` package, like this:

\usepackage{graphicx,dashrule,doc,colordoc,fancyhdr}

(The `doc` package defines the `\EnableCrossrefs` macro.) My recommendation, just in case it's not clear, is to load neither the `doc` nor the `colordoc` package.

Whatever else you do, *don't* load the `epsfig` package -- the more so since you're already loading the `graphicx` package.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I'm not sure why my prof. used colordoc. Why wouldn't you need it?

Comment: @TheDetective - The abstract of the package's user guide consists of the following statement: "The `colordoc` package builds on the `doc` package to provide color highlighting of TEX syntactical conventions, especially curly braces, `\if...\fi` pairs, and definitions." Unless your document is about documenting TeX and LaTeX code -- which, judging by the rest of the preamble, is exceedingly unlikely -- there should be absolutely no need or reason for loading the `doc` and `colordoc` packages. You should ask your professor what induced him (her?) to load the `colordoc` package...