# how to construct multi images using latex

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

[image]

Please see the above image. There are four images,and I want to use figure environment of latex to construct these images(1,2,1). What should I do?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Second}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Third}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Fourth}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{All figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't subfigure package obsolete, alternative would be to use [caption](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) package https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200/15717

Comment: @texenthusiast Yes, `subfigure` is quite old.  Better use `subcaption`.