# TeX Capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] Babel ngerman

Tags: errors, compiling, babel

I have an error on my latex document. If I put in

```
\usepackage[ngerman,german]{babel}
```

into my header file, I get the following log:

```
...
)
\babel@savecnt=\count89
\U@D=\dimen104
)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<inserted text> 
                U
l.41 ...Init\CurrentOption{captions\CurrentOption}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

I need this library, for different language settings, as well for my master thesis the layout should be fixed.

Is there a way to get around the error?

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,DIV=15,BCOR=20mm,parskip=half,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{german, ngerman} %Deutsche Trennungen, Anführungsstriche und mehr
\usepackage[ngerman, german]{babel} % dt. Sprache laden (u.a. auch Ausgabe feststehender Begriffe in deutsch wie etwa Inhaltsverzeichnis statt table of contents)
\begin{document}

\section*{Notes for My Paper}

Don't forget to include examples of topicalization.
They look like this:

{\small
\enumsentence{Topicalization from sentential subject:\\ 
\shortex{7}{a John$_i$ [a & kltukl & [el & 
  {\bf l-}oltoir & er & ngii$_i$ & a Mary]]}
{ & {\bf R-}clear & {\sc comp} & 
  {\bf IR}.{\sc 3s}-love   & P & him & }
{John, (it's) clear that Mary loves (him).}}
}

\subsection*{How to handle topicalization}

I'll just assume a tree structure like (\ex{1}).

{\small
\enumsentence{Structure of A$'$ Projections:\\ [2ex]
\begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
    & \node{i}{CP}\\ [2ex]
    \node{ii}{Spec} &   &\node{iii}{C$'$}\\ [2ex]
        &\node{iv}{C} & & \node{v}{SAgrP}
\end{tabular}
\nodeconnect{i}{ii}
\nodeconnect{i}{iii}
\nodeconnect{iii}{iv}
\nodeconnect{iii}{v}
}
}

\subsection*{Mood}

Mood changes when there is a topic, as well as when
there is WH-movement.  \emph{Irrealis} is the mood when
there is a non-subject topic or WH-phrase in Comp.
\emph{Realis} is the mood when there is a subject topic
or WH-phrase.

\end{document}
```

Comment: How should we know if you don't show the rest of your header? But I doubt very much that you need both german and ngerman, or do you write half of your text with old spelling?

Comment: Well the error disappears if I comment that line. But then i lose some of my german translations. I know very little about latex at the moment. I just took the template from my university

Comment: Well I don't this error if I add the line (and as you can guess I'm a german and so often use it), so something in the rest of your document is probably responsable. You will have to show it a complete example that other can test on their pc.

Comment: Then please post that template, preferably with a link to where it can be downloaded. Then others can test it. Templates often contain errors or are not updated in time. But we need exact code in order to replicate the problem, until then we cannot help. But as Ulrike mentions you are very likely not needing both German option, I think most just use ngerman

Comment: Why do you need both `ngerman` and `german`? Does `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` work?

Comment: I added the template

Comment: I won' t download a 2 MB archive. Try to make a minimal example that you can copy here in the question.

Comment: @samcarter tried it. unfortunately it is not working. same error

Comment: @K213 Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: i'll try to build one

Comment: I posted a quick minimal example. For some reason, this works on my work pc, but not on my two different home pcs.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, using the `babel` package should be enough, no need for `\usepackage{german,ngerman}` (both packages are in the list of outdated packages https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200/36296). The `babel` package also enables hyphenation etc. For quotations marks I suggest to either enter them manually or use the `csquotes` package.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,DIV=15,BCOR=20mm,parskip=half,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{ngerman} %Deutsche Trennungen, Anführungsstriche und mehr
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % dt. Sprache laden (u.a. auch Ausgabe feststehender Begriffe in deutsch wie etwa Inhaltsverzeichnis statt table of contents)
\begin{document}

\section*{Notes for My Paper}

Don't forget to include examples of topicalization.
They look like this:

\subsection*{Mood}

Mood changes when there is a topic, as well as when
there is WH-movement.  \emph{Irrealis} is the mood when
there is a non-subject topic or WH-phrase in Comp.
\emph{Realis} is the mood when there is a subject topic
or WH-phrase.

\end{document}
```

*(I removed some of the body content as I have no idea how `\enumsentence` or `\shortex` might be defined)*