# Removing spacing before appendix and TOC title and contents on separate sheets

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, chapters, titlesec, appendices

I am having trouble with the Table of contents and the list of figures: The title and the entries are showing on two pages.
How do I remove the big space before apendix and vita.

```
\documentclass[]{report} 
\usepackage[md]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage[verbose]{cite} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{CHAPTER \arabic{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}%all headings must be displayed in ToC.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}%numbers all headings; not actually required (can set to 0 instead of 3 if wanted)
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}%this is a kludge; ignore it
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\normalfont} %changes font of chapters & parts in ToC.  removes bold, for instance
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{.25in}{.25in}%indents the chapters & sections in the ToC
\cftsetindents{section}{.5in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{.75in}{.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{1in}{.5in}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip} %these make the ToC single spaced within chapters, but keep it double spaced elsewhere
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\newenvironment{MyFigure}[1][]{\begin{figure}[#1]\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\end{figure}}
\doublespacing %double space
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
    %DO NOT USE \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}% lowercase roman numerals for pre-document stuff
    \chapter*{}
    \begin{center}
    \vfill
    Copyright \copyright\ 2017
        All Rights Reserved
    \vfill
    \end{center}
    \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ABSTRACT}
    \large
    \paragraph{Test}

    \chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
        %\subfile{sections/Acknowledge}

    \chapter*{DEDICATION}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}DEDICATION}
    %\subfile{sections/Dedication}

    \chapter*{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \vspace{-4\baselineskip}
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF FIGURES}

    \chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    \subfile{sections/Los}

    \chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    \subfile{sections/Loa}


    \cleardoublepage
    \cleardoublepage
    \large
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}% Arabic numerals, starting at 1, for the actual document


    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\contentsline{part}{.}{}}


\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\label{Intro}
\section{Background}
\label{Backgrnd}
%\subfile{Sections/Background}

\section{Questions and Limitations}
\label{Quest}
%\subfile{Sections/quest}

\chapter{RELATED WORKS}
\label{RelWorks}
%\subfile{Sections/Relworks}

\chapter{METHODOLOGY}
\label{Method}
%\subfile{Sections/Methodology}

\chapter{RESULTS}
\label{Result}
\%subfile{Sections/Result}

\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\label{Conclusion}
%\subfile{Sections/conclusion}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}REFERENCES}
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\setstretch{1} %this single spaces within bib entries, but keeps double spaces between entries

%\bibliography{ref}
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{part}{APPENDIX }{}}
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{APPENDIX  \Alph{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter }{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}
\chapter{Equations }
\label{eqn}
%\subfile{Sections/Equation}
\clearpage
%\chapter[\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}FINAL APPENDIX TITLE]{ Equation}%the last appendix needs to be added strangely


\clearpage
\chapter*{VITA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{VITA}
\large
%\subfile{Sections/Vita}
\end{document}
```

TOC: [image: TOC]

Appendix: [image: Appendix]

Comment: There is no need to load `epsfig`. See [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention in your preamble

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}%this is a kludge; ignore it
```

This *kludge* is an issue. While it removes the titles of the ToC, it doesn't change the mechanism associated with printing these. Inherently, `\tableofcontents` is set as a `\chapter*` under the `report` document class. And these chapters are set on a clean page (executing `\cleardoublepage` before setting the chapter title). So, even though you say

```
\chapter*{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
\tableofcontents
```

`\tableofcontents` still calls `\chapter*{\contentsname}`, which clears the current page. Instead, you probably want to

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
```

and set an appropriate `\titlespacing` to enforce your negative `\vspace` prior to setting the ToC. This way you can just call `\tableofcontents` and it will set the heading the way you want, together with the spacing and the actual ToC.

The same discussion above holds for `\listfigurename`/`\listoffigures` and `\listtablename`/`\listoftables`.

---

Immediately before setting your Appendix and Vita chapters, you change the chapter title format and spacing using the following:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{APPENDIX \Alph{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}
```

Specifically, here's the definition of `\titlespacing` from the [`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (section **3.2 Spacing**):

> ```
> \titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}[<right-sep>]
> ```
>
> The starred version kills the indentation of the paragraph following the title, except in `drop`, `wrap` and `runin` where this possibility does not make sense.
>
> - `<left>` increases the left margin, except in the `...margin`, and `drop` shape, where this parameter sets the title width, in `wrap`, the maximum width, and in `runin`, the indentation just before the title. With negative value the title overhangs.
> - `<before-sep>` is the vertical space before the title.
> - `<after-sep>` is the separation between title and text-vertical with `hang`, `block`, and `display`, and horizontal with `runin`, `drop`, `wrap` and `...margin`. By making the value negative, you may define an effective space of less than `\parskip`.
> - The `hang`, `block` and `display` shapes have the possibility of increasing the `<right-sep>` margin with this optional argument.

You're explicitly setting `<before-sep>` to `250pt`, which is very large. It is the cause behind your titles being pushed down to the bottom of the page on these `\chapter`s.