# How to make the subfigure numbering and reference styles like: (a) xxx, Figure 2a?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

For subfigure numbering and reference: the following styles are wanted

...

(a) Figure 1   (b) Figure 2

...

The reference should be: xxx as shown in Figure 1.a and 1.b  (or 1a and 1b).

Because it looks awardard like: xxx (see Figure 1(a) and 1(b)).

How to make this happen using `subfigure` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`subfigure`](//ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is considered [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764).

This is the default behaviour when using the [`subcaption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) together with a standard `\ref` (works with [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as well):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

See Figure~\ref{fig:figure}. 
Also, see Figures~\ref{fig:subfig-left} and~\ref{fig:subfig-right}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Left subfigure\label{fig:subfig-left}}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
  \subcaptionbox{Right subfigure\label{fig:subfig-right}}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm. btw, how to make `Figure 1` bold face but (a) ... normal?

Comment: @KOF: Add `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold}{\textbf{#1~#2}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat = bold}` to your preamble after loading the [`subcaption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).

Comment: Figure is bold face, but colon `:` is not. I need to delete it by `\captionsetup{labelsep = space}`.

Comment: @KOF: Okay. If you want to keep and **bold**, it seems to suffice to use `\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont = bf}`.

Comment: What I did is manually adding `:` --- `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold}{\textbf{#1~#2:}} \captionsetup[figure]{labelformat = bold}
\captionsetup{labelsep = space}`